# C++ Get name of type in template

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time, typename

I'm writing some template classes for parseing some text data files, and as such it is likly the great majority of parse errors will be due to errors in the data file, which are for the most part not written by programmers, and so need a nice message about why the app failed to load e.g. something like:

> Error parsing example.txt. Value ("notaninteger")of [MySectiom]Key is not a valid int

I can work out the file, section and key names from the arguments passed to the template function and member vars in the class, however I'm not sure how to get the name of the type the template function is trying to convert to.

My current code looks like, with specialisations for just plain strings and such:

```
template<typename T> T GetValue(const std::wstring &section, const std::wstring &key)
{
    std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring>::iterator it = map[section].find(key);
    if(it == map[section].end())
        throw ItemDoesNotExist(file, section, key)
    else
    {
        try{return boost::lexical_cast<T>(it->second);}
        //needs to get the name from T somehow
        catch(...)throw ParseError(file, section, key, it->second, TypeName(T));
    }
}
```

Id rather not have to make specific overloads for every type that the data files might use, since there are loads of them...

Also I need a solution that does not incur any runtime overhead unless an exception occurs, i.e. a completely compile time solution is what I want since this code is called tons of times and load times are already getting somewhat long.

EDIT: Ok this is the solution I came up with:

I have a types.h containg the following

```
#pragma once
template<typename T> const wchar_t *GetTypeName();

#define DEFINE_TYPE_NAME(type, name) \
    template<>const wchar_t *GetTypeName<type>(){return name;}
```

Then I can use the DEFINE_TYPE_NAME macro to in cpp files for each type I need to deal with (eg in the cpp file that defined the type to start with).

The linker is then able to find the appropirate template specialisation as long as it was defined somewhere, or throw a linker error otherwise so that I can add the type.

Comment: not really relevant to your question, but you might want to use map.find(section) when accessing the section aswell, unless you intentionally want to create an empty section.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Jesse Beder's solution is likely the best, but if you don't like the names typeid gives you (I think gcc gives you mangled names for instance), you can do something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeParseTraits;

#define REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE(X) template <> struct TypeParseTraits<X> \
    { static const char* name; } ; const char* TypeParseTraits<X>::name = #X


REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE(int);
REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE(double);
REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE(FooClass);
// etc...
```

And then use it like

```
throw ParseError(TypeParseTraits<T>::name);
```

EDIT:

You could also combine the two, change `name` to be a function that by default calls `typeid(T).name()` and then only specialize for those cases where that's not acceptable.

Comment: Note: This code will not compile if you forget to define REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE for a type that you use. I have used a similar trick before (in code without RTTI) and it has worked very well.

Comment: I had to move name outside of the struct in g++ 4.3.0 due to "error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type 'const char *'"; and, of course, the keyword 'struct' is needed between <> and TypeParseTraits and the definition should be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Well the leaving the semicolon out was intentional, to force you to use it at the end of the macro invocation, but thanks for the corrections.

Comment: I obtain the folllowing error: `error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter`

Comment: @kratsg - that's because at the end '#x' should be '#X' (uppercase to match macro parameter) - I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 117):

The solution is:

```cpp
typeid(T).name()
```

where `typeid(T)` returns [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info).

Comment: Keep in mind that it's compliant to return the same string for every type (though I don't think any compiler would do that).

Comment: Or to return a different string for the same type on different executions... (again not that I think that any sane compiler would do that).

Comment: I'd just like to point out how ugly the given name can be: `typeid(simd::double3x4).name() = "N4simd9double3x4E"`. `typeid(simd::float4).name() = "Dv4_f"` C++17, Xcode 10.1.

Comment: Indeed.  `typeid(T).name()` is the canonical way to do this, but very few compilers return unmangled names; the only one I'm personally familiar with that does so is MSVC.  Depending on the compiler used, there's also a chance that it may lose some type information on function types, but that's _probably_ irrelevant in this case.

Comment: `typeid(T).name()` does not return `std::type_info`, but `char const *`.

Answer (score 65):

`typeid(T).name()` is implementation defined and doesn't guarantee human readable string.

Reading [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) :

> Returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string
>   containing the name of the type. No guarantees are given, in
>   particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and
>   change between invocations of the same program.
>
> ...
>
> With compilers such as gcc and clang, the returned string can be piped through c++filt -t to be converted to human-readable form.

But in some cases gcc doesn't return right string. For example on my machine I have gcc whith `-std=c++11` and inside template function `typeid(T).name()` returns `"j"` for `"unsigned int"`. It's so called mangled name. To get real type name, use 
 [abi::__cxa_demangle()](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html) function (gcc only):

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cxxabi.h>

template<typename T>
std::string type_name()
{
    int status;
    std::string tname = typeid(T).name();
    char *demangled_name = abi::__cxa_demangle(tname.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &status);
    if(status == 0) {
        tname = demangled_name;
        std::free(demangled_name);
    }   
    return tname;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it memory leak to have `free` in `if`?

Comment: No, because the pointer points to `nullptr` if the status is not 0.

Comment: I'd like to add that it's probably best to check for gcc or clang's existence and if not default to not doing the demangling [as shown here](http://ideone.com/sqFWir).

Comment: This solution does not display type qualifier (e.g. const) there is a [similar approach that display both type and qualifier here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25893042/2273600)

Answer (score 27):

As mentioned by Bunkar typeid(T).name is implementation defined.

To avoid this issue you can use [Boost.TypeIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_typeindex/getting_started.html) library.

For example:

```
boost::typeindex::type_id<T>().pretty_name() // human readable
```

Comment: This is very useful for finding out templates type names when functions are called. It worked pretty well for me.

Comment: Note that pretty_name() or raw_name() is still implementation defined. On MSVC for a struct A; you would get : "struct A" while on gcc/clang : "A".

Comment: wow. `boost` again for the win. amazing what boost does without compiler support (`auto`, `regex`, `foreach`, `threads`, `static_assert`, etc, etc... support before compilers/C++-standard support).

Answer (score 27):

This trick was mentioned under a few other questions, but not here yet.

All major compilers support `__PRETTY_FUNC__` (GCC & Clang) /`__FUNCSIG__` (MSVC) as an extension.

When used in a template like this:

```
template <typename T> const char *foo()
{
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    return __FUNCSIG__;
    #else
    return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    #endif
}
```

It produces strings in a compiler-dependent format, that contain, among other things, the name of `T`.

E.g. `foo<float>()` returns:

- `"const char* foo() [with T = float]"` on GCC
- `"const char *foo() [T = float]"` on Clang
- `"const char *__cdecl foo<float>(void)"` on MSVC

You can easily parse the type names out of those strings. You just need to figure out how many 'junk' characters your compiler inserts before and after the type.

You can even do that completely at compile-time.

---

The resulting names can slightly vary between different compilers. E.g. GCC omits default template arguments, and MSVC prefixes classes with the word `class`.

---

Here's an implementation that I've been using. Everything is done at compile-time.

Example usage:

```
std::cout << TypeName<float>() << '\n';
std::cout << TypeName<decltype(1.2f)>(); << '\n';
```

Implementation: (uses C++20, but can be backported; see the edit history for a C++17 version)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string_view>

namespace impl
{
    template <typename T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr std::string_view RawTypeName()
    {
        #ifndef _MSC_VER
        return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
        #else
        return __FUNCSIG__;
        #endif
    }

    struct TypeNameFormat
    {
        std::size_t junk_leading = 0;
        std::size_t junk_total = 0;
    };

    constexpr TypeNameFormat type_name_format = []{
        TypeNameFormat ret;
        std::string_view sample = RawTypeName<int>();
        ret.junk_leading = sample.find("int");
        ret.junk_total = sample.size() - 3;
        return ret;
    }();
    static_assert(type_name_format.junk_leading != std::size_t(-1), "Unable to determine the type name format on this compiler.");

    template <typename T>
    static constexpr auto type_name_storage = []{
        std::array<char, RawTypeName<T>().size() - type_name_format.junk_total + 1> ret{};
        std::copy_n(RawTypeName<T>().data() + type_name_format.junk_leading, ret.size() - 1, ret.data());
        return ret;
    }();
}

template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr std::string_view TypeName()
{
    return {impl::type_name_storage<T>.data(), impl::type_name_storage<T>.size() - 1};
}

template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr const char *TypeNameCstr()
{
    return impl::type_name_storage<T>.data();
}
```

Comment: THAT is the real answer!!  Absolutly beatifull, no need std lib, and it runs complie time.  In embedded code, this is the only solution.  Thank you!!

Comment: I like this answer as well, but beware [GCC < 8.0 does not define `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` as a `constexpr`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66639) - which is on the default `gcc` on Ubuntu 18.  Also, here is [a similar-in-concept implementation](https://bitwizeshift.github.io/posts/2021/03/09/getting-an-unmangled-type-name-at-compile-time/) (also based on `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`).

Comment: This worked for me. I directly printed the string output of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. My codebase didn't support typeid.

Answer (score 14):

The answer of Logan Capaldo is correct but can be marginally simplified because it is unnecessary to specialize the class every time. One can write:

```
// in header
template<typename T>
struct TypeParseTraits
{ static const char* name; };

// in c-file
#define REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE(X) \
    template <> const char* TypeParseTraits<X>::name = #X

REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE(int);
REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE(double);
REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE(FooClass);
// etc...
```

This also allows you to put the REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE instructions in a C++ file...

Answer (score 8):

As a rephrasing of Andrey's answer:

The [Boost TypeIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_typeindex.html) library can be used to print names of types.

Inside a template, this might read as follows

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void printNameOfType() {
    std::cout << "Type of T: " 
              << boost::typeindex::type_id<T>().pretty_name() 
              << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like a pretty_name, Logan Capaldo's solution can't deal with complex data structure: `REGISTER_PARSE_TYPE(map<int,int>)`
and `typeid(map<int,int>).name()` gives me a result of `St3mapIiiSt4lessIiESaISt4pairIKiiEEE`

There is another interesting answer using `unordered_map` or `map` comes from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <typeindex>
using namespace std;
unordered_map<type_index,string> types_map_;

int main(){
    types_map_[typeid(int)]="int";
    types_map_[typeid(float)]="float";
    types_map_[typeid(map<int,int>)]="map<int,int>";

    map<int,int> mp;
    cout<<types_map_[typeid(map<int,int>)]<<endl;
    cout<<types_map_[typeid(mp)]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`typeid(uint8_t).name()` is nice, but it returns "unsigned char" while you may expect "uint8_t".

This piece of code will return you the appropriate type

```
#define DECLARE_SET_FORMAT_FOR(type) \
    if ( typeid(type) == typeid(T) ) \
        formatStr = #type;

template<typename T>
static std::string GetFormatName()
{
    std::string formatStr;

    DECLARE_SET_FORMAT_FOR( uint8_t ) 
    DECLARE_SET_FORMAT_FOR( int8_t ) 

    DECLARE_SET_FORMAT_FOR( uint16_t )
    DECLARE_SET_FORMAT_FOR( int16_t )

    DECLARE_SET_FORMAT_FOR( uint32_t )
    DECLARE_SET_FORMAT_FOR( int32_t )

    DECLARE_SET_FORMAT_FOR( float )

    // .. to be exptended with other standard types you want to be displayed smartly

    if ( formatStr.empty() )
    {
        assert( false );
        formatStr = typeid(T).name();
    }

    return formatStr;
}
```

Comment: This is great, but why not do `return #type;` instead?

Comment: @LittleHelper: You are right, that would also work...

Answer (score 1):

Since c++20 we can use `std::source_location::function_name()` to get a string containing the function name and arguments.

```
template<typename T>
consteval auto type_name()
{
    std::string_view func_name(std::source_location::current().function_name()); // returns something like: consteval auto type_name() [with T = int]

    auto extracted_params = ... Do some post processing here to extract the parameter names.
    return extracted_params;
}
```

N.B.: at the time of writing (Oct 2022) MSVC does not report the template parameters, so this solution will not work there. Unfortunately, the form of the return value of `function_name()` isn't specified in the standard, but we may at least hope that they will add the template parameters in later versions.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/e7aebG7q1)

Answer (score 0):

There're many good answers here, but I'd guess the easiest is to use a library, isn't it?
You can use [this tiny lib](https://github.com/AVasK/typo), it's pretty cross-platform (tested with recent GCC/Clang/MSVC/ICC), supports C++11 onwards, works at compile time (consteval since C++20) and in theory it's going to support every compiler since the C++20's <source_location> gains wider support. A few more notes are in the README :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this trick to publish a service interface with type information

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const char* nameOfType(int& ){ return "int";}
const char* nameOfType(const char* &){ return "string";}
const char* nameOfType(float& ){ return "float";}
const char* nameOfType(double& ){ return "double";}

template <typename T> 
const char* templateFunction(T t){
  return nameOfType(t)  ;
};

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World this is an ";
    cout << templateFunction<int>(1) << std::endl;
    cout << templateFunction<const char*>("") << std::endl;
    cout << templateFunction<double>(3.14) <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the awesome answer by @HolyBlackCat which does the job at compile time. I've managed to encapsulate the logic inside a struct so there's no need for a "impl" namespace, instead the 'impl' functions are guarded in a `private` manner.

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeInfo
{
    private:
        struct RawTypeNameFormat
        {
            std::size_t leading_junk = 0;
            std::size_t trailing_junk = 0;
        };

        template<typename U>
        static constexpr const auto& RawTypeName()
        {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
            return __FUNCSIG__;
#else
            return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
#endif
        }

        // Returns `false` on failure.
        static constexpr inline bool GetRawTypeNameFormat(RawTypeNameFormat *format)
        {
            const auto &str = RawTypeName<int>();
            for (std::size_t i = 0;; i++)
            {
                if (str[i] == 'i' && str[i+1] == 'n' && str[i+2] == 't')
                {
                    if (format)
                    {
                        format->leading_junk = i;
                        format->trailing_junk = sizeof(str)-i-3-1; // `3` is the length of "int", `1` is the space for the null terminator.
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        static constexpr inline RawTypeNameFormat format =
        []{
            static_assert(GetRawTypeNameFormat(nullptr), "Unable to figure out how to generate type names on this compiler.");
            RawTypeNameFormat format;
            GetRawTypeNameFormat(&format);
            return format;
        }();


        // Returns the type name in a `std::array<char, N>` (null-terminated).
        [[nodiscard]]
        static constexpr auto GetTypeName()
        {
            constexpr std::size_t len = sizeof(RawTypeName<T>()) - format.leading_junk - format.trailing_junk;
            std::array<char, len> name{};
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
                name[i] = RawTypeName<T>()[i + format.leading_junk];
            return name;
        }

    public:
        [[nodiscard]]
        static cstring Name()
        {
            static constexpr auto name = GetTypeName();
            return name.data();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        static cstring Name(const T&)
        {
            return name();
        }
}
```

Example usage:

```
auto myTypeName = TypeInfo<MyType>::Name();
```

or:

```
const char* myTypeName = TypeInfo<MyType>::Name();
```

Answer (score -1):

I just leave it there.
If someone will still need it, then you can use this:

```
template <class T>
bool isString(T* t) { return false;  } // normal case returns false

template <>
bool isString(char* t) { return true; }  // but for char* or String.c_str() returns true
.
.
.
```

This will only CHECK type not GET it and only for 1 type or 2.