# has_type template returns true for struct type {};

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits

There are a number of ways to implement a `has_type<T>` template that deduces if `T` has a nested class or typedef named `type`.  ie

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename> struct tovoid { typedef void type; };
}

template<typename T, typename = void> struct has_type
    : std::false_type { };
// this one will only be selected if C::type is valid
template<typename C> struct has_type<C, typename detail::tovoid<typename C::type>::type>
    : std::true_type { };
```

Or

```
template <typename C> char test_for_type(...) { return '0'; }
template <typename C> double test_for_type(typename C::type const *) { return 0.0; }

template <typename T> struct has_type
{
    static const bool value = sizeof(test_for_type<T>(0)) == sizeof(double);
};
```

however in either case, `has_type<type>::value` is `true` for this class:

```
struct type
{
};
```

Now the above `type` doesn't have another `type` nested within it, but it does have a constructor `type::type()`.

But should that constructor 'trigger' the checks for the nested type? Or is it a compiler bug?
(I would like to think that `typename type::type` didn't apply to a constructor and/or that you couldn't take a pointer to a constructor, such as what would be produced by the second test method: `typename type::type const *`.

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of a class is "injected" into the scope of the class, so `type::type` really is the name of a type, and it's the same type as `::type`.

Comment: Ah, true.  And I guess `struct type { struct type {}; };` is invalid, as is `struct type { typedef int type; };`.   Which answers my next question - how to handle this case (if I really wanted to).  And that would be by checking if T is named type, which shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @tony Harder and less portable than you would think: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1055452/501250

Comment: @cdhowie getting the type name as a string is tricky, but I don't need that.  I just need: class type;

template <typename T>
struct is_type_type
{
    static const bool value = std::is_same<T, type>::value;
};

Comment: @tony and you do that for *all namespaces ever*?

Comment: It is probably not something worth "fixing" I guess.  `struct type {};` according to the standard, _does_ have a type `type`, so I guess `has_type<type>::value` should be true anyhow...

Comment: and no one is going to use has_type on a type named type anyhow.

Comment: @tony I had the same thought regarding `std::is_same`. :( What we'd need to make that work is a mechanism to deduce the namespace of a type template argument and append `::type` to it.

Comment: grrr.  Same problem, now real world (particularly for Range algorithms that take both Iterators and Containers) - how to tell an Iterator from a Container.  First thought is to look for `T::iterator`, but that exists for all Iterators named "iterator"....

Comment: is_iterator<T> can be implemented via: An iterator is either a pointer, or has a member type iterator_category.  (That doesn't cover someone's iterator that doesn't have a category, but it probably should have a category.)   In C++14 iterator_traits will be SFINAE-able.