# Template meta programming : print type list

Tags: c++, templates

How can I print a type list ??

here is what I tried + my type list :

```
template<typename ...T>
struct typeList;
template<typename H, typename ...T>
struct typeList<H, T...> {
    using head = H;
    using tail = typeList<T...>;
public:
    static inline void print(){
        std::cout << H::name << " "; // How can I get the name of H ???
        typeList<T...>::print();
    }
};

template<>
struct typeList<>{
   static inline void print(){
       std::cout << endl;
   }
};
```

so that `typeList<A,B,C,int>::print()` would give `A b C int` ,

A B and C are some user defined structs

Can I do this without adding a static function called `name` in every struct?? 
There is no compile time function that returns the type name ?

**EDIT :**

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/print-variable-type-in-c), where did I mention variables ??

Comment: Is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid insufficient?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe A `type_info` object is not required to give you a useful name.

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate, because the main question appears to be about printing the name of a type. If that's the case, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1055452/493122) might also help.

Comment: @Jefffrey anyway, my question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/print-variable-type-in-c

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun How come?

Comment: @Jefffrey I am not printing the name of a variable

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun I know, but that question have [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/493122) answer, which deals with how to print the type after you get it from the variable, which is indeed a duplicate of what you are asking here. Also have you tried [reading the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055452/c-get-name-of-type-in-template) I linked?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `typeid(H).name()` for this. Unfortunately, format of `name()` is implementation defined, so you can't rely on getting the output you expect in all cases.

For example, in GCC 4.9.2, `typeList<A,B,C,int>::print()` prints:

```
1A 1B 1C i
```

A possible solution would be to define a `getTypeName` template function which you specialize for the different types, then fall back on `typeid().name()` when you don't have a specialization:

```
template <typename T>
std::string getTypeName()
{
    return typeid(T).name();
}

template <>
std::string getTypeName<int>()
{
    return "int";
}

template <>
std::string getTypeName<A>()
{
    return "A";
}
```

This would print out:

```
A 1B 1C int
```

Then you could easily add specializations for your other types.