# Getting name of class type by specialization of class template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to set variable `name` of  template class `A` by it's definition.

I was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055563/9616495) answer. 
My current files looks like this:

**Header file**

```
namespace N {
    // Definition of class A
    template <class T> class A {
    public:
         A();

         static const char* name;
    }

/*1*/ #define REGISTER_TYPE(T) template <> class N::A<T>::name = #T;
}
```

**Source file**

```
namespace N {
    template<class T>
    A<T>::A() 
    {
        //empty constructor
    }
}
REGISTER_TYPE(N::MyOtherClass);
```

But somehow, error messages `'name' in 'class N::A<N::MyOtherClass>' does not name a type` and `expected unqualified-id before '=' token` (line with `/*1*/`) pops up, but variable with this name exists.

I am using C++17. I have already tried to

Where am I doing mistake?

Thanks for your help!

//EDIT:

Solved in comments. Result is:

`#define REGISTER_TYPE(T) template <> const char * N::A<T>::name = #T;`

Comment: forgotten some `:`? I mean: `class N::A<T>::name` instead of `class N:A<T>::name`?

Comment: You must use the actual type of `name` when defining it. It's not a `class`.

Comment: @max66 Thanks, my mistake, fixed

Comment: @Brykyz - `REGISTER_TYPE` is the same as `REGISTER_FILTER`?

Comment: @max66 Yes, it is

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Does that mean that 'name'  is supposed to be class? If that's case, how can I assign #T to variable name?

Comment: @Brykyz - As you can see, you've corrected two times your code. Code that is incomplete. How can we try to respond to your question if you don't show us an **exact** and complete, but minimal, code that reproduce the problem?

Comment: Have you ever used `static` member variables before? If so how did you define them in the source files? Using `class` or using the actual type of the variable?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So if I understand, instead of `template <> class N::A<T>::name = #T` I should use `template <> const char* N::A<T>::name = #T`, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok, it's working, thanks for your help!