# Macro or template to shorten repeated use of static_assert

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, static-assert

This question is partly common to [C++ Get name of type in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055452/c-get-name-of-type-in-template) .
I am trying to come up with a template/macro that expand to `static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value, #T" is not trivally destructible");` so that I can use a shorthand in my code. But looks like there is no compile time way of knowing the name of T in a template.

The other approach of using a macro is also not good since it will move the errors to incorrect line numbers (i.e. within the macro). See example of errors with a macro as below:

```
macro.cpp:5:17: error: static assertion failed: std::vector<int> should be trivial 
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value, #T" should be trivial"); 
^~~ 
macro.cpp:10:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘STATIC_ASSERT_TRIVIALLY_DESTRUCTIBLE’ 
STATIC_ASSERT_TRIVIALLY_DESTRUCTIBLE(std::vector<int>); 
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: This would really need to be forwarded by a macro, but from the caller's site unfortunately. I've got low hopes to get this working in a reasonable way. Would be interested to see an answer.

Comment: Regarding the macro: most compilers will additionally report the line on which the macro was used.

Comment: Are you constrained to C++14? There may be a way to do this with `std::source_location` from C++20 though I'm not sure about that at all.

Comment: @cigien yes, unfortunately can't go past c++14 as of now.

Comment: Please add all that relevant information to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for adding the error messages. You don't need to mention that you're restricted to C++14, that's implied by the tag. My comment was simply asking for a confirmation about that.

Comment: Hmm. The title seems to suggest that you're looking for a more concise way of doing `static_assert`, but the body of your questions seems that you're more interested in finding a way to output the value of `T` correctly. I'd search for "compile time printing". [Here's an example](https://github.com/saarraz/static-print) of someone who's managed something similar to what you want.