# macro in template class not work as I expected

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a macro defined in a template class to use the real class Name.
It may be not clear, and the code is below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void Test_CB()
{
}

#define TEST_INTERFACE(xx) Test_##xx()


template <class T>
class CA
{
public:
    void Write()
    {
        TEST_INTERFACE(T);
    }
};

class CB : public CA<CB>
{

};


int main()
{
    CB b;
    b.Write();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope the result is `class name:CB` but on gcc, it output `class name:T`
Is there any way to make it work as windows?

---

Maybe there is a problem with my presentation, I mean the visual c++ on windows and gcc on linux.
I don't only want to get the type name. What I want is an identifier with part of the class name. I update the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Get name of type in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055452/c-get-name-of-type-in-template)

Comment: Macros work at preprocessor time. It wouldn't really know what you've passed `T` as in that time because it hasn't even started compiling the program. It just stringifies the exact parameter it is given.

Comment: A better solution would be to use [this template trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59522794/1678770) to extract the type-name by leveraging either `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` or `__FUNCSIG__`

Comment: *"to make it work as windows"* I would say you also have `class name:T` on windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because template resolution happens during compile phase and pre-processor directives are resolved before compilation. Hence in this case when pre-processor is run, the macro receives the class as `T` hence the macro is replaced with `"T"`.

What you need is this : [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

add `#include <typeinfo>`

and replace the `cout` statement with:

```
std::cout << "class name:" << typeid(T).name();
```

Comment: `typeid(...).name()` is not guaranteed to yield the exact type-name as in source. In fact, `gcc` and `clang` both use this to output the *mangled name* instead -- which is often undesirable for logging.