# How to debug and print a template alias type c++

Tags: c++, templates, type-alias

I have some nested typedefs which I am trying to debug. The first I want to do is to print them out so I can see how they are instantiated.

E.g.

```
 using tt = std::conditional<conditionForType1, type_1, type_2>;
```

where `type_1` and `type_2` are two other evaluated aliases. How can I print the content of `tt`, `type_1`, and `type_2`

Comment: If you want to print the type at run-time, I'd start with [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty way:

```
template <typename T>
void print_type()
{
    #ifndef _MSC_VER
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    #else
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << '\n';
    #endif
}
```

What exactly is printed depends on the compiler. For `print_type<int>();`, my Clang prints `void print_type() [T = int]`.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59522794/2752075) for removing anything other than the type name from such strings.

Comment: What does it print if you pass `print_type<tt>()`?

Comment: @jxh On my Clang it prints `void print_type() [T = std::conditional<true, type_1, type_2>]` (given `constexpr bool conditionForType1 = true;`).

Comment: Works with GCC too. Now, I'm curious what MSVC would print.

Comment: @jxh `void __cdecl print_type<struct std::conditional<1,struct type_1,struct type_2>>(void)` I know you're expecting one of them to print `tt`, but nope. If it worked like this, it could have some use for stateful metaprogramming...

Comment: The reason I half thought it would is because I originally tested `void print_type(tt){ ... }` and that is what it print.

Answer (score 1):

I use the compiler to handle this for me. By declaring a class template like

```
template <typename T>
struct type;
```

and not defining it, you can use it in code like

```
int main()
{
    struct foo {};
    struct bar {};
    
    foo f;
    
    type<int>{};
    type<decltype(f)>{};
    type<bar>{};
}
```

Which will give you a compiler error like

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:25:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct type<int>'
   25 |     type<int>{};
      |               ^
main.cpp:14:8: note: declaration of 'struct type<int>'
   14 | struct type;
      |        ^~~~
main.cpp:26:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct type<main()::foo>'
   26 |     type<decltype(f)>{};
      |                       ^
main.cpp:14:8: note: declaration of 'struct type<main()::foo>'
   14 | struct type;
      |        ^~~~
main.cpp:27:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct type<main()::bar>'
   27 |     type<bar>{};
      |               ^
main.cpp:14:8: note: declaration of 'struct type<main()::bar>'
   14 | struct type;
      |        ^~~~
```

And it gives you the type used in the template parameter as a convenient error message.

Answer (score 0):

The [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator returns an object of type [`type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info), which has a `name()` method. You can use this to get a string representation of the type.

```
std::cout << typeid(tt).name() << '\n';
```

If you use [g++](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b), there is an [API](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) you can call to demangle the name into something more human readable. On my system, the program:

```
using tt = std::conditional<true, int, double>;

int main () {
    int status;
    auto &&ti = typeid(tt);
    char *pretty = abi::__cxa_demangle(ti.name(), 0, 0, &status);
    std::cout << ti.name() << '\n';
    std::cout << pretty << '\n';
    free(pretty);
}
```

Produces the output:

```
St11conditionalILb1EidE
std::conditional<true, int, double>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7bioMwEIbv8xQDCzYubtlra32SBZkms3ZAE0kmYCl9djdW2QNsyM1/4JvfTNNbb8zyws4MyRI07KMEwrFVP57cJuokIEv8bZt5xgsfr61aUmTXgwicIYqta@OdZWHvcGgkJKqAnVRgfboM1J6UyhJGZAe6hLuC/FYnCkqKp6fGJB6KQjgz1wFstUi5ZeaKAV6nQCK3HOcVdd11ZsbO0oiuH0gLHx2OpMsK3p@/2OA7YV@ZBJoGvrurOHy4wz@d/difwmcg0luQsY9l@QI)