# Get full name of C++ class member variable

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose I have the following class

```
namespace example {

class Test {
public:
    int a;
};

};
```

The fully scoped name of this variable would be "example::Test::a"

My question is, is there some way to get this information at **compile-time** and have it placed into a sting **within the class**?  For example, I want the result to be equivalent to:

```
namespace example {

class Test {
public:
    int a;

    static const char* a_name() { return "example::Test::a"; }
};

};
```

Where the a_name() method is "auto-generated" at compile time.

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name

Comment: it might be useful to have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c but it is only partially address your problem

Comment: @AlanBirtles -- that gives the "name" of the **type** of the object, in some implementation-specific form.

Comment: `return __FUNCTION__;`

Comment: The last semi-colon is not required. Please delete it!

Answer (score 4):

The name of `a` itself is not accessible in any way without using features that are not officially part of C++. If you want to stay standard-compliant, you will have no choice but to manually fill in that part.

Beyond that, if you have access to `<cxxabi.h>`, you can fill in the rest with `typeid()` and `abi::__cxa_demangle`, but at that point, you'll have to start concatenating strings at runtime, which is not great, but it does get you close to where you want to be.

```cpp
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cxxabi.h>

template<typename T>
std::string member_name(const char* name) {
   int status = 0;
   auto type_name = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), 0, 0, &status);

   // Feel free to return an error string instead of throwing an exception, obviously...
   if(status != 0) throw std::runtime_error("failed to lookup type name");
   std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> cleanup(type_name, std::free);

   return std::string(type_name) + "::a";
}

namespace example {
class Test {
public:
    int a;

    static std::string a_name() { 
      return member_name<Test>("a"); 
    }
};
}

int main() {
  std::cout << example::Test::a_name() << "\n";
}
```

**Edit:**

If you are willing to go outside of the bounds of standard C++, then you can use compiler-specific macros and a bit of constexpr juggling with `std::string_view` to get the member name at compile time.

This is adapted from the solution presented at [C++ Get name of type in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055452/c-get-name-of-type-in-template/59522794#59522794) (Thanks @HolyBlackCat!)

```
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {

struct Placeholder {
  int member;
};

template<auto T>
constexpr std::string_view raw_member_name() {
  #ifdef _MSC_VER
  return __FUNCSIG__;
  #else
  return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
  #endif
}

constexpr std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> member_name_offsets() {
  std::string_view raw = raw_member_name<&Placeholder::member>();
  std::string_view lookup = "detail::Placeholder::member";

  auto leading = raw.find(lookup);
  auto trailing = raw.size() - lookup.size();
  return {leading, trailing};
}
}

template<auto T>
constexpr std::string_view member_name() {
    constexpr auto offsets = detail::member_name_offsets();
    std::string_view pretty = detail::raw_member_name<T>();
    return pretty.substr(offsets.first, pretty.size() - offsets.second);
}

namespace example {
class Test {
public:
    int a;

    static constexpr auto a_name = member_name<&Test::a>();
};
}

int main() {
  std::cout << example::Test::a_name << "\n"; // outputs: "example::Test::a"
}
```

If you absolutely must have a null-terminated string, you'll have to also copy the bytes into a `std::array<char, L+1>` as well.

Comment: the user was looking for a compile-time solution, could the function be marked as constexpr?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi I've managed to cobble something together, but it's certainly not something I'd like to see in production code.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Here's the same `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`-based approach, in a more production-ready form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055452/c-get-name-of-type-in-template/59522794#59522794

Comment: @Frank What do you mean? I calculate the offsets.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh, I see what's going on in there. Yeah, that should be adaptable to this scenario as well (with a placeholder struct type instead of int). Thanks for the callout. I had missed that part on my quick read through.