# How to fix 'cxxabi.h' file not found error?

Tags: c++

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 version and I'm getting this error when trying to compile my project which depends on this [cmdline](https://github.com/tanakh/cmdline) open source project.

```
cmdline.h(39,10): fatal error : 'cxxabi.h' file not found
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: I'm not seeing the `cxxabi.h` include in https://github.com/FlorianRappl/CmdParser/blob/master/cmdparser.hpp

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Link fixed. I didn't like the lib name so I changed the name..

Comment: Well, the lib doesn't support MSVC it seems. But the fix is easy: replace their `readable_typename()` function with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59522794/2752075), which doesn't need `<cxxabi.h>`. Or check out one of the several unmerged PRs that fix MSVC compatibility.

Comment: I do see it on line 39. A search says it is in [libstc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.6/dir_00818abdbffa3fdf9d4e4b8402db6c97.html).

Comment: @lakeweb The link was edited since I posted the comment. :|

Comment: Ah, ok @HolyBlackCat I get what that means.

Comment: How about just use [Boost Program Options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/program_options.html)? I use it and it works very well.

Comment: @lakeweb Large refactoring ;(

Comment: @HolyBlackCat They don't have anything called `readable_typename()`, what they have is `char *p=abi::__cxa_demangle(name.c_str(), 0, 0, &status);`

Comment: `readable_typename()` is 7 lines below that line.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, I found it. I also found complete answer in an issue of their repo.