# Unexpected behavior with std::is_same_v

Tags: c++, templates

I was writing a function that checks what type a pointer was pointing to, but std::is_same_v returns false when you make the pointer const.

Here is a minimal reproducible example of what is supposed to work:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr bool checkType() {
    return std::is_same_v<std::remove_pointer_t<std::remove_cv_t<std::decay_t<T>>>, char>;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(checkType<char*>(), "char* should be true");
    static_assert(checkType<const char*>(), "const char* should be true");
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried changing the order of `std::remove_cv_t<std::decay_t<T>>` to `std::decay_t<std::remove_cv_t<T>>` or even getting rid of `std::decay_t` altogether, but it still does not work. I've also tried checking the type returned by `std::remove_pointer_t` with this code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void do_() {
#define cx std::remove_pointer_t<std::remove_cv_t<std::decay_t<T>>>
    std::cout <<
    "T: " << typeid(T).name() << " (" << typeid(T).raw_name() << "), " <<
    "Tred: " << typeid(cx).name() << " (" << typeid(cx).raw_name() << "), \n" <<
    "icb?: " << (std::is_same_v<cx, char> ? "true" : "false") << ", " <<
    "iib?: " << (std::is_same_v<cx, int> ? "true" : "false")
    << "\n";
}

int main() {
    do_<char>();
    do_<char*>();
    do_<const char*>();
    do_<int>();
    do_<int*>();
    do_<const int*>();
    return 0;
}
```

which returns the following:

```
T: char (.D), Tred: char (.D),
icb?: true, iib?: false
T: char * __ptr64 (.PEAD), Tred: char (.D),
icb?: true, iib?: false
T: char const * __ptr64 (.PEBD), Tred: char (.D),
icb?: false, iib?: false
T: int (.H), Tred: int (.H),
icb?: false, iib?: true
T: int * __ptr64 (.PEAH), Tred: int (.H),
icb?: false, iib?: true
T: int const * __ptr64 (.PEBH), Tred: int (.H),
icb?: false, iib?: false
```

which doesnt make any sense to me since the name of the types are the same... but arent the same type?
I'm using Clang 17.0.4 (C++23), but I've also tested this in MSVC (C++20) and the same behavior occurs.

Comment: `const char*` is a "(non-const) pointer to const char". `decay_t` has no effect on it, because it's not const and not a reference. `remove_cv_t` has no effect because it's not const. `remove_pointer_t` turns it into "const char".

Comment: why would typeid(cx).raw_name() return the same raw name as char or int then?

Comment: `typeid` ignores top-level constness and referenceness. Here's an approach that doesn't: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59522794/2752075