# How to convert typename T to string in c++

Tags: c++, templates

While playing with templates in c++ I encountered a problem converting typename T to string. For example:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
   public:
        Matrix() {
           //my_type = string type of T. i.e. if T is char. I want my_type to be "char".
        }
   string my_type;
}
```

How do I convert T to a string that says what T is.

Note: I'm just playing around so please do not worry about when one might need such a thing.

Comment: Checkout: https://github.com/gelldur/common-cpp/blob/master/src/acme/type_name.h

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c/56766138#56766138

Answer (score 86, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism for this.

`typeid(T)::name()` can give some info, but the standard does not mandate this string to be human-readable; just that it has to be distinct for each type. (E.x. Microsoft Visual C++ uses human-readable strings; GCC does not.)

You can build your own system though. For example, traits-based. Something like this:

```
// default implementation
template <typename T>
struct TypeName
{
    static const char* Get()
    {
        return typeid(T).name();
    }
};

// a specialization for each type of those you want to support
// and don't like the string returned by typeid
template <>
struct TypeName<int>
{
    static const char* Get()
    {
        return "int";
    }
};

// usage:
const char* name = TypeName<MyType>::Get();
```

Comment: Generating that specialization is arguably a case for a macro: `#define ENABLE_TYPENAME(A) template<> struct TypeName<A> { static const char *Get() { return #A; }};`. Then when I write my class `Foo` I can do `ENABLE_TYPENAME(Foo)`, putting it in the right namespace if necessary.

Comment: "just distinct for each type" no, you don't even have this guarantee

Comment: Note that GCC gives Itanium ABI mangled names, which can be demangled with an Itanium ABI function.

Comment: I had to omit the `template <>` part of the specialization to get it to work. Borland C++ (yes, a legacy 20+ years old compiler).

Comment: Not related, but this answer explains this other [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562961/5972766)

Answer (score 25):

For GCC you have to use a trick. Using `cxxabi.h`, I wrote a little wrapper for this purpose:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>

#define DEBUG_TYPE(x) do { typedef void(*T)x; debug_type<T>(T(), #x); } while(0)

template<typename T>
struct debug_type
{
    template<typename U>
    debug_type(void(*)(U), const std::string& p_str)
    {
        std::string str(p_str.begin() + 1, p_str.end() - 1);
        std::cout << str << " => ";
        char * name = 0;
        int status;
        name = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(U).name(), 0, 0, &status);
        if (name != 0) { std::cout << name << std::endl; }
        else { std::cout << typeid(U).name() << std::endl; }
        free(name);
    }
};
```

The double parentheses are necessary. Will work with any type.

Now you can use it for `boost::mpl`:

```
DEBUG_TYPE((if_c<true, true_, false_>::type));
```

will print:

```
if_c<true, true_, false_>::type => bool_<true>
```

Comment: would this not make it processor-specific for the Itanium 64-bit ?? or is this usable on other architectures?

Comment: @serup abi::__cxa_demanble should be available with gcc on any architecture (e.g. I've used it on ARM).

Answer (score 7):

You can't, at least not directly.  The only way to convert a token or series of tokens into a string literal is using the preprocessor's stringization operator (`#`) inside of a macro.

If you want to get a string literal representing the type, you'll have to write something yourself, perhaps by using a macro to instantiate the template and pass it the stringized type name.

One problem with any general approach is:  what string should be given for the following uses:

```
Matrix<char> x;
typedef char MyChar;
Matrix<MyChar> y;
```

Both `x` and `y` are of the same type, but one uses `char` directly and the other uses the typedef `MyChar`.

Answer (score 7):

It is impossilbe to get name of type in `string` if the type is one of base types. For user defined types you can use `typeid(my_type).name()`. Also you need `#include <typeinfo>` :)
[more info...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid)

Answer (score 1):

workaround way...

```
#define Tprint(x) print<x>(#x)

template<typename T>
void print (string ltype){
cout<<ltype<<" = "<<sizeof(T)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Excuse me for poor formatting. My first post in stackover flow.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you do `Tprint(T)` where `T` is the template parameter given in the original question, you'll get `T = 4` or some number. You won't get the type of T written to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [C++ reflection library](http://billyquith.github.io/ponder/). So:

```
using namespace ponder;

Class::declare<Matrix>();

std::string const& name = classByType<Matrix>().name();
```

This gives you other options as well once you have the metaclass information, like looking what the class members are.

Answer (score -6):

```
template< typename From,typename To>
static inline bool superConvert(const From& fromVar,To& toVar)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<fromVar;
    ss>>toVar;
    if(ss.fail())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        From tempFrom;
        stringstream ss;
        ss<<toVar;
        ss>>tempFrom;
        if(tempFrom != fromVar)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand how is this relevant to the question.

Comment: you can convert any type to string,

Comment: You misunderstood the question, he's trying to get the string name of the type that is used in template. Essentially `std::string type = "<T>"` only that doesn't work.