# Generate a string based upon a class template's typename?

Tags: c++, class, templates, macros, c-preprocessor

### What I'd like to be able to do...

I have a templated class which sets up a (named) shared memory pool based upon the type of object passed as the type parameter. I was wondering if, possibly through the aid of [preprocessor operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wy090hkc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or otherwise, there was a way to "stringize" the typename, and append an identifier?

Something along the lines of the syntax: ***<classtype>_identifier***
Where `MyClass<int>` would generate `int_identifier`...
For example:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
private:
    #define TYPENAME_STRING(s) T_#s
    std::string m_typeName;

public:
    MyClass(std::string objName = "ObjectName")
    {
        // This:
        m_typeName = TYPENAME_STRING(objName.c_str());
        // ...Obviously doesn't work, since this is the equivalent of typing:
        m_typeName = "T_ObjectName";
        // ...When what we really want is something like:
        m_typeName = "int_ObjectName";
    }
    ~MyClass();        
};
```

Getting this to work would be useful to name, create and manage psuedo-unique memory pools based entirely upon the type of object being passed as the type parameter.

### Is something like this possible?

*Also*, is it possible to resolve this typename and prepend it to an identifier *WITHOUT* being "stringized" (i.e., to create a typedef *named* `intObjectName`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not possible, at least not at that level. Macros are evaluated before compilation, that is, before template type parameters like the `T` in your example are evaluated. What you could do however is something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
template <class T> struct TInfo;
template <class T> class MyClass;

#define TINFO(type)                                \
template <> struct TInfo<type> {                   \
  static char const* getName() {                   \
    return #type;                                  \
  }                                                \
};                                                 \
typedef MyClass<type> type##_Class;                \
typedef std::unique_ptr<MyClass<type>> type##_UPtr; 


template <class T>
class MyClass {
private:
  std::string m_typeName;

public:
  MyClass(std::string objName = "ObjectName") 
    : m_typeName(std::string(TInfo<T>::getName()) + "_" + objName)
  {}

  std::string const& getName() {
    return m_typeName;
  }
};


//usage:
#include <iostream>

TINFO(int);
int main()
{
  int_UPtr pi(new int_Class());
  std::cout << pi->getName() << '\n';
}
```

See http://ideone.com/3ivyqv

Comment: +1 for the reason _why_ my example won't work, plus a working example.
But is there also a way to generate typedefs which use the same naming convention?

Comment: However, try to make the macro stuff as short and plain as possible. Debugging it is impossible, and compiler errors coming out of macroed code are hard to resolve.

Comment: The explanation for why this work is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4485051/5972766)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to have your types stringified :

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    static const char *name; // Not private
// ...
};

#define DECLARE_MY_CLASS(x) template<> const char *MyClass<x>::name = #x;

DECLARE_MY_CLASS(int);
```

But you need to `DECLARE_MY_CLASS` all your types you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misreading this but you can get the string of a typename using typeid as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass 
{
private:
  const static std::string s_typeName;

public:

  const std::string getName() const 
  {
      return s_typeName;
  }
};

template<typename T>
const std::string MyClass<T>::s_typeName = std::string(typeid(T).name()) + "_identifier";
```

Comment: Just FYI, while you're not wrong, the return value of `.name()` is implementation dependent and is usually not "useful" per se. For instance, `unsigned int` is returned as `"j"` on my compiler.