# Is it possible to include a type `T`'s string expansion into the error message given by `static_assert`?

Tags: c++11, c++14

This is a follow up questions from [How to convert typename T to string in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484982/how-to-convert-typename-t-to-string-in-c)

I am asking because I would really like to generate nice error messages like

```
static_assert(one_of<T,Components...>::value,
              "Unable to access T because you didn't 
              use it in filter<Components...>.");
```

Would print

```
Unable to access Foo because you did not use it in filter<Bar,Baz,Bat>.
```

Is something like this now possible in C++11 / 14?

Comment: That's very different to just converting it to a string, because the conversion has to take place at a very specific time in the compilation process and not at runtime.

Comment: Unfortunately, `static_assert`'s second argument must be a *string-literal*, which means you have to assemble the string *prior* to compilation, e.g. by using the preprocessor *shudder*. The preprocessor however does not know that type some template parameter `T` of a specific specialization of a template refers to.

Comment: I clarified the question's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [from](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) the poor(lazy?) man's version of the [C++ Standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/),

> Since message(the second argument to static_assert) has to be a string literal, it cannot contain dynamic information or even a constant expression that is not a string literal itself. Typically, it cannot contain the name of the template type argument.

So, there isn't a way of getting the friendly `static_assert` error messages you desire.

Answer (score 0):

No, no it is not possible to do that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh he interpreted his question to be a question actually about `static_assert` and whether it supports a certain feature and not about converting `T` to its string representation in general. And he answered with "no, it is not possible". IMO it is a reasonable interpretation of a (slightly) ambiguous question and a reasonable answer.

Comment: I think the OP's example makes it quite clear what he wants to do, and my answer clearly answers it.