# Why does decltype on value returned from template function return T

Tags: c++, types

I have been trying to implement a linked list using `unique_ptr` and add an iterator to it. I have run into a particular problem. When I try to use `decltype` on the first element of the list using my iterator, I get an error about `invalid type "T"`.

Can someone please explain the origin of this error?

Below is an example that reproduces the error.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class MyListItr;

template<typename T>
class MyList {
private:
    int _size;
    friend class MyListItr<T>;
public:
    class Node {
    private:
        T value;
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<MyList::Node> next{ nullptr };

        Node() = delete;
        Node(T& value) :value(value), next(nullptr) {};
        Node(MyList<T>::Node& ref) :value(ref.value), next(std::move(ref.next)) {};
        T getVal()const { return value; };
        void setVal(T value) { this->value = value; };
        ~Node() {};
    };

    std::unique_ptr<MyList::Node> head;
    MyList(const MyList<T>&) = delete;
    MyList& operator=(const MyList<T>) = delete;
    MyList() :_size(0), head(nullptr) {};
    int size()const { return _size; };
    void push_front(T);
    T pop_front();
    T front()const;
    MyListItr<T> begin() {
        typename MyList<T>::Node* tmp = this->head.get();
        return  MyListItr<T>::MyListItr(tmp);
    };
    MyListItr<T> end() { return MyListItr<T>::MyListItr(nullptr); };
    typedef MyListItr<T> iterator;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef size_t size_type;

};

template<typename T>
class MyListItr : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, T> {
    typename MyList<T>::Node* data;

public:
    MyListItr(typename MyList<T>::Node* data) :data(data) {}

    bool operator!=(MyListItr<T>const& T)const;
    MyListItr<T> operator++();
    T operator*();

};

template<typename T>
void MyList<T>::push_front(T x) {
    std::unique_ptr<MyList::Node>tmp = std::move(this->head);
    this->head = std::make_unique<MyList<T>::Node>(MyList<T>::Node(x));
    this->head->next = std::move(tmp);
    _size++;
};

template<typename T>
T MyList<T>::pop_front() {
    if (this->_size == 0)throw std::out_of_range("Range exceeded");
    T tmp = this->head.get()->getVal();
    this->head = std::move(this->head->next);
    _size--;
    return tmp;
};

template<typename T>
T MyList<T>::front()const {
    return this->head.get()->getVal();
};

template<typename T>
bool MyListItr<T>::operator!=(MyListItr<T>const& Itr)const {
    return this->data != Itr.data;
};

template<typename T>
MyListItr<T> MyListItr<T>::operator++() {

    return(this->data->next.get());
};

template<typename T>
T MyListItr<T>::operator*() {

    return (this->data->getVal());
};


int main() {
    MyList<int> l;
    l.push_front(4);
    std::cout<< *l.begin();
    std::cout << decltype(*l.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `std::cout << decltype(*l.begin());` to try and print out the objects type?

Comment: What did you *expect* in place of `T`? And *why*?

Comment: You cannot `std::cout` the result of `decltype` any more than you can do `std::cout << int;`.

Comment: frankly, you seem to misunderstand what `decltype` does. To clear that up you need to explain what you think it does.

Comment: ok, so I didn,t know that you cant print that and thought that it reproduces the same error that I wanted to show it being that call to `std::is_same_v<decltype(*l.begin()), int&>` return false, and I wasexpecting it to return true, as the elemtn accesed is an int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decltype()` gives you just that: a type. Not a string. You can't stream a type to the console like you are trying to.

If you want to get a string representation of some type, [you can do that, though not in a portable fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4484982/4386278).

Comment: ok I did not know that, but when i try to do
`std::is_same_v<decltype(*l.begin()), int&>` it returns false despite the fact that the list was created as <int> so

Comment: Another link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c

Comment: @KonradP Don't quote me on this (I'm multitasking) but it may be `int` in that context, not `int&`. Please read [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)! Also there are other errors with your code which means I can't just quickly try it, which is a shame. A [mcve] would have been better.

Comment: @KonradP No, it is `int`, not `int&`, because your `operator*` implementation (erroneously) returns `T` instead of `T&`.

Comment: Ok I see my mistake now I was indeed returning an int and not int&, have now changed how the operator* works and it's fine, Thanks for help.