# Is a C++ is_lambda trait, purely implemented as a library, impossible?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, traits

I have a question regarding C++0x lambdas. In my code, it would be beneficial to know whether or not a given type is the type of a C++0x lambda expression. To give an example:

```
struct foobar
{
  void operator()()
  {
  }
};

auto lambda = []{};
typedef is_lambda < decltype(lambda) > ::type T; // T would be a true_type
typedef is_lambda < foobar > ::type T; // T would be a false_type
```

It is rather easy to distinguish lambda expressions from function and member function types. Functors are another matter.

The problem I see here is the definition of lambda expressions according to the upcoming C++0x standard; the only thing that must be defined is a public call operator. However, this is true for a functor as well; testing for the presence of the call operator is not enough for distinguishing lambda expressions from functors. Furthermore, if the operator of a functor is *not* present, a compiler error will occur, since SFINAE does not apply. When does this happen? The functor's call operator may be templated.
So, such a code:

```
typedef decltype(&T::operator()) call_type;
```

will work for both lambda expressions and functors with non-templated call operator, and generate a compiler error for templated call operators.

I believe an `is_lambda < >` trait can only be created using intrinsic compiler features. Do you see a way how to implement this trait?

Comment: I wonder what would you use it for?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I think I made a logical error. There is no point in distinguishing regular functors from lambdas - I can view the latter as the former. However, there is need for determining whether or not a call operator exists. To this date, no fully generic solution for this problem seems to exist. I will address this in a separate question soon, along with my attempts.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: As for a motivating difference: the type of a *closure object* uniquely identifies it implementation. The same is not (necessarily) true for other function pointers or other function like objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since evaluation of lambda results in creating closure object, there isn't any difference as soon as the object passed to a function or copied. And, frankly, I can't imagine a problem that would require to know whether an object came from lambda.

Edit. A standard even has a note in 5.1.2/2:

> Note: a closure object behaves like a function object (20.8).—end note

Comment: I do imagine that you could be willing to know whether a `std::function<...>` type is stateful or not. However since functions are allowed to use `static` or global variables, their would not be much point in distinguishing lambdas from the mix.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe that it can be done- lambdas aren't really anything new semantically, they're just compiler-generated functors and thus will look identical to regular functors.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to define some macro code that determines if an expression is a lambda *expression* (but that's not very useful as it doesn't tell you if an expression is of a lambda *type*).

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U>
struct SameType {
    static_assert(!std::is_same<T, U>::value, "Must use Lambda");
    static T pass(T t) { return t; }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
T NotLambda(T t, U u) { return SameType<T, U>::pass(t); }

#define ASSERT_LAMBDA(x) NotLambda(x,x)

/////////////////////////////////////

int fn() { return 0; }

int main() {
    auto l = []{ return 0; };
    return ASSERT_LAMBDA(fn)() +             // << fails
           ASSERT_LAMBDA(l)() +              // << fails
           ASSERT_LAMBDA([]{ return 0; })(); // << passes
}
```

This depends on section 5.1.2.3 which specifies that each lambda expression has a distinct type (which I think is a property unique to lambdas).

Comment: I had the same idea. If only it could be done without the ugly macro, but while I find the syntax of using `NotLambda` directly (with a lambda expression twice), to be tolerable, a user could of course accidentally provide two distinct function objects.

Answer (score 1):

I created a header-only compiler specific (msvc >= 19.20?, gcc >= 7.3, clang >= 6.0) `is_lambda` type trait in c++17 if anyone interested in.

https://github.com/schaumb/is_lambda-cpp-type-trait

This can be used as in the question:

```
struct foobar
{
  void operator()()
  {
  }
};

auto lambda = []{};
typedef bxlx::is_lambda < decltype(lambda) > T; // T is true_type
typedef bxlx::is_lambda < foobar > U; // U is false_type
```

There are more [examples](https://github.com/schaumb/is_lambda-cpp-type-trait/blob/master/assert_tests.cpp#L49) for the usage.

---

Comment: TL;DR: the idea is to use [`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c) to determine the name of the type, and check if looks like `"lambda at foo.cpp"`.