# typeid(T).name() alternative in c++11?

Tags: c++, reflection, c++11

Is there a standard way in c++11 to get the name of a class either with some template black magic or dynamically with some standard library function?

Comment: @spraff, the name representation is not standard though.

Comment: Note that if you want to also have the CV qualifiers, you can use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/1593077) due to @HowardHinnant . It's still based on `typeid(T).name()` though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once I found the pretty printing of the function prototype quite useful:

In GCC, **PRETTY_FUNCTION** contains the type signature of the function as well as its bare name.

For example for a templated class or function you get the class names expanded as a C-string:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector {
  void foo(int i) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  }
};
```

This would give you something like

```
void Vector<double>::foo(int)
```

If you had instantiated the class with, e.g. doubles. But it gives you also user defined types.

Not very fancy, but it has its uses.

Comment: `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is an extension of GCC.

Answer (score 8):

No, but you could make one:

```
template<class T> struct meta {
    static const std::string& get_name() {return T::class_name;}
};
```

and then either add the static member `class_name` to the class:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static const std::string class_name("MyClass");
};
```

or specialize meta:

```
template<> struct meta<int> { 
    static const std::string class_name("int");
    static const std::string& get_name() {return class_name;}
};
```

(here's a macro to make that easier)

```
#define specialize_meta(name) template<>struct meta<name>{static const std::string class_name(#name); static const std::string& get_name() {return class_name;} };
specialize_meta(double);
```

and then use the meta template:

```
int main() {
   std::cout << meta<int>::get_name();
}
```

If you *really* want to get crafty, you can make a version for functions too, but these would (obviously) have to be specialized.

```
void foo(int) {} //function in question
template<class T, T& a> struct metafunc; //dont define generic.
template<decltype(foo), &foo> struct metafunc { //specialization
    static const std::string func_name("void foo(int)");
}
```

Comment: If everything returned `std::string const&` instead of `std::string` there would be far fewer copies. :-] Also, `meta<>::get_name()` should be static.

Comment: @ildjarn: I had made them return copies so implimenters of `class_name` could assemble more complex strings in a full function rather than requiring it to be static `std::string` member.  I couldn't' come up with a use-case however, so I went with your suggestion.

Comment: this requires some work on the target class. I cannot do that.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: No it doesn't.  It's _easiest_ to modify the target class, but note that I also got it to work for `int`, which I obviously did not modify.  Simply specialize the meta class.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: Added a macro to make it _super_ easy to add specializations.