# How to determine actual object type at runtime in C++;

Tags: c++, typeid, typeinfo

Lets say we have a class hierarchy. At the bottom we have Base and at the top Derived.
How to determine object class even if it is converted to base class pointer.

```
Base* b = new Derived():

typeid(b).name(); // i want this to tell me that this is actually derived not base object
```

is there any way other than manual implementation of string field or such and virtual get function?

PS: I talking about compiler-independent solution

Comment: This is possible as explained in the answer, but this is almost always a wrong thing to do. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Nothing exactly it is just for the purpose of argueing :)

Comment: More application oriented version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c || More generic version that does not mention inheritance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310898/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-a-variable

Answer (score 33, accepted):

make sure the base class has at least one virtual method, include `<typeinfo>` and use your current code just with an additional dereferencing, `typeid(*b).name()`.

---

in passing, note that a `typeid` call is the one place in C++ where you can dereference a nullpointer with well-defined behavior, which implies that it can throw an exception:

> **C++11 §5.2.8/2**:
>   “If the glvalue expression is obtained by applying the unary `*` operator to a
>   pointer and the pointer is a null pointer value (4.10), the `typeid` expression throws the `std::bad_typeid` exception (18.7.3).”

Comment: It is a good idea to have destructor as "at least one virtual method"

Answer (score 16):

If all you want to do is find if `b` actually points to `Derived`, just use `dynamic_cast()`:

```
if (dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b)) { ... }
```

`dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer if the actual runtime type of the object pointed to by `b` is not `Derived` (or a class derived from `Derived`). Unlike the `name()` member of `std::type_info`, this is compiler-invariant.

Note that this only works if `Base` has at least one virtual member functions. Which it should anyway, since you're manipulating types derived from it through a base pointer, so it should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: But the case is that i dont want to modyfy code anytime i add new class.

Comment: It does not return null for the base class (Clang).