# How to check the type of variable in conditional statement

Tags: c++

How can I check the type of a input variable inside `if` clause in C++?
If there is any member function to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the type of a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310898/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-a-variable)

Comment: Please provide some sample code to show what you want to do.

Comment: Wanting to do this indicates a design problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type checks you want to do.

The simplest is probably

```
 #include <typeinfo>     // for the `std::type_info` type

 if (typeid(input_variable) == typeid(chosen_type))
 {
      // input_variable is of type chosen_type
 }
```

It is also possible to check the (implementation defined) name strings that identify a type

```
 if (std::string(typeid(input_variable).name()) == typeid(chosen_type).name())
 {
      // input_variable is of type chosen_type
 }
```

The conversion to `std::string` is needed for comparison operators to work, as the `.name()` member function returns `const char *`.   Otherwise compare the `name()` members using `strcmp()` (either in C's `<string.h>` or in C++ `<cstring>` - within namespace `std`).

Bear in mind that the character sequence returned by `typeid(X).name` is implementation defined.

In C++11, the `type_info` type has a `hash_code()` member, which may also be compared.  The values of this are implementation defined, and may vary between executions of the program.   Furthermore, as Martin Bonner mentioned in comments, that `hash_code()` may give false positives for equality (if `hash_code()`s compare non-equal, the types are different but if they compare equal the types *may* be different.   I mention this, not because I advocate comparing `hash_code()`s, but because the original question has not explained *why* comparison of types is desired, so there is no basis to assume a test that might yield false matches is inappropriate.

Comment: hash_code is not guaranteed to be different for different types.  In other words, it's a good value to feed to unordered_map, but not to prove equality (use `typeinfo::operator =()` for that)

Comment: As I said, it depends on the type of comparison desired.   If `hash_code()` results compare not equal, the types are different.   If they compare equal, the types *may* be different, so there is a non-zero likelihood of false matches.   Potential comparisons with a likelihood of false positives (or false negatives) are a valid screening technique in some applications.

Comment: Exactly!  I only commented because the OP might have been under the impression that equality of `hash_code()` proved equal types.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use:

```
typeid(yourvariable).name()
```

You need to include the following header to make it working:

```
#include <typeinfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy to use solution would be the following one:

```
#include<cassert>

struct B { static int cnt; };
int B::cnt = 0;

template<class T>
struct S: B { static int type; };

template<typename T>
int S<T>::type = B::cnt++;

template<typename T, typename U>
bool f(T, U) {
    return S<T>::type == S<U>::type;
}

int main() {
    assert(f(42, 0));
    assert(!f(0, .0));
}
```

You can use `S<T>::type` in a guard statement or wherever you want.
If you have a variable named `x`, is a matter of using something like:

```
S<decltype(x)>::type
```