# How to make condition for specific template datatypes

Tags: c++, templates, stack

so i made a very simple stack that works just fine and decided to turn it to template, it also worked fine, but when i turned it to integer something happened with the input

```
string m;
    getline(cin, m);
    linkedliststack<int> str;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++)
    {
        str.push(m[i]);
    }
```

It appeared that by using this input method the m[i] becomes char turned to int, in other words turned to ASCII code, so if i enter 1 it give 48, 2 give 49 etc.
The simple solution is of course this.

```
str.push(m[i]-48)
```

But is there a way to make it automated, e.i. with if condition or anything? 
If yes then what is the required syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not cast it? str.push((int)(m[i]))

Comment: You're not looking for data type conversion, you're looking for parsing a string into a numeric value.

Comment: Possibly look into using stoi Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/

Comment: The problem is easy to solve i just want it to be automated, e.g. detect that the template is now <int> and then activates 'str.push(m[i]-48)' by itself

Answer (score 0):

Strings push_back is

```
void push_back (char c);
```

i.e. it takes a `char`. If you want the value as a `char` you have to convert it by using e.g. [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) or the like.

Answer (score 0):

I must apologize for repeating this question as it is related to this on [How do I get the type of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310898/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-a-variable)
sorry this is my first time to ask a question.

So to solve this i made a new function in the class

```
string type(){ return  typeid(head->value).name(); }
```

and the new condition solves the problem.

```
if (str.type()== "int")
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be an enable_if solution out there if you're able to use C++14.
 Maybe even an SFINAE solution. However I'm not very experienced with that.

I'm assuming your push method is declared as

`void push(typename T);`

Then what you are doing is implicitly converting a char `(m[i])` to an int `str.push(m[i]);`

You could provide an overloaded template method that can handle a char Input and convert it correctly to your typename.

Something like this:

```
void push(const char input)
{
    push(atoi(input));
    // push(input-48);
}
```

A lot of errors may have to be considered though:
What happens if atoi() cannot convert the char to an integer?
In your case of -48 you will push unintended numbers on the Stack if input is a nonnumber char.
What will happen if the template is not instantiated with .