# error : expected primary-expression before 'decltype'

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I am trying to find the type of variable. In stackoverflow it is mentioned that `decltype()` is used for that purpose. But when I tried to used it is throwing me the error as I mentioned in title.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    cout << decltype(x);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected `int` but it showing as error. `error: expected primary-expression before 'decltype'`

Comment: You can't `cout << int;` either.

Comment: You meant `typeid(x).name()`.

Comment: Have a look in the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310898/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-a-variable

Comment: @chris so you mean to decltype() doesn't output string. Thanks.

Comment: @LogicStuff Yeah I used it. But some where in stackoverflow they mentioned that decltype is better than typeid().name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Types aren't first class objects. You can't pass a type to a function, and `cout << decltype(x)` is exactly that, passing a type to a function (though beautified by the operator).

To get an info about the type of a variable, you can

1. Read the code. If the type of an object is `int`, don't bother printing it.
2. Step through your program with a debugger. It shows the type of variables.
3. Use this (non-standard) function template

   ```
   template <class T> void printType(const T&)
   {
       std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
   }

   printType(x);
   ```
4. Use Boost.

   ```
   #include <boost/type_index.hpp>

   std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(x)>().pretty_name() << "\n";
   ```

Comment: Hi, how to get the boost module? apparently I don't have it in my machine. Is there a "python pip" like package manager for c++. I installed conan I don't know what to do next?

Comment: "Is there a "python pip" like package manager for c++" - you can't ask a more intricate question :) Anyway, google should help. If you're stuck, do some research and post a new question.

Comment: lol.. okay... I will accept your answer as soon as I tested your code. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Your answer has all non-standard solutions though. There is a hack using template where you make the compiler to tell the type with the following error where unsigned int is the type of object passed - 'error C2079: 'b' uses undefined struct 'A<unsigned int>''.