# What is the difference between `long long int a=50` and `int a =50LL`?

Tags: c++, types

I have started learning C++ from Josh Lospinoso's C++ Crash Course.

I am unable to wrap my mind around 'types'.

What is the difference between `long long int a=50` and `int a =50LL` ?
To me, they both look like `long long int`

I tried to run this:

```
#include<cstdio>
int main() {
    long long int a=50;
    int b=50LL;
    printf("a is %lld and b is %lld",a,b);
}
```

and got :

> a is 50 and b is 18042367336513586

So there is something wrong with either the format specifier or `int b=50LL`

On changing the format specifier of b to `%d`. I get:

> a is 50 and b is 50

So does this mean that `b` is the default 'int' ? If yes, what is the role of `LL` then?

On surfing about types, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310898/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-a-variable).
So I tried running this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main(){
    long long int a = 50;
    int b = 50LL;
    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which gave

> x
> i

So they are indeed of different types (?). But Why?

Comment: Mismatching `printf` format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. The variable `b` is an `int`, you should use a format specifier that matches it.

Comment: No the `int a=50LL;` will still be an `int`. If you can use C++20 consider using std::format (instead of printf), and if you can use C++23 use [std::print](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print)

Comment: The problem with first value of `b` is in `printf`. You use format specifier for `long long int ` and load normal `int` in stack. Then function `printf` uses random values following bytes of `int` (50). Probably you have ignored warnings.

Comment: `int` is not `long long int`.  They are different types.  When you do `int b = 50LL;` the **50LL** gets converted from a long long int to an int.

Comment: Instead of using runtime typeid, check your types with a compile time assert and [<type_traits>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits). E.g. `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a),int>);` and you will see that `a` is not a `long long` but an `int` too

Comment: @i486 I didn't get any warning. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px40I.png)

Comment: Printing an `int` (i.e. `b` in your code) using the `%lld` format gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Wolgwang -- You lied to `printf` and told it that `b` is a `long long int` when it actually is an `int`.  And since you used `cout`, you could have simply outputted `std::cout << a << " "  << b;` and saw they had the same *value*.

Comment: Don't use `printf`. `std::cout << "a is " << a << " and b is " << b << '\n';`

Comment: *I didn't get any warning.*  Do you even have warnings turned on?  If you don't turn them on, you don't get them.  In the olden days, we'd use a **lint** program to find problems, but since then the lint functionality has been rolled into the compiler itself (because we have faster machines and more memory).

Comment: @Eljay How to turn that on? (I am a noob, sorry )

Comment: `g++ -Wall -Wextra test.cpp` or `clang++ -Weverything test.cpp`

Comment: try `unisgned x = -1;` and `int y = -1;`. `-1` is signed in both cases, but `x`s value will be diffferent.

Comment: What an unfortunate choice in naming. Are you sure you want to take a course in making C++ crash?

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry, but how is the choice in naming unfortunate?

Comment: "C++ Crash Course" Generally you don't want to write programs that crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
long long int a=50;
```

This declares a `long long int` variable, and initializes it to 50.

```
int a =50LL;
```

This declares an `int` variable, and initializes it to 50. The constant value 50 is lexically specified as a `long long` integer constant, which gets converted to an `int`, for the purpose of initializing `a` (accomplishing absolutely nothing useful, by itself, whatsover).

So the difference is that you end up with either a `long long int` or an `int` variable named `a`. In both cases they are initialized to 50.

Answer (score 1):

##### The problem is the call to printf, not the initialization.

`%lld` is the wrong `conversion specification` for variable `b`, which has type `int`. Use `%d` instead.

- `%lld` means output a value of type `long long int` in decimal format (rather than hex or octal).
- `%d` means output a value of type `int` in decimal format (rather than hex or octal).

The garbage output is explained by the different sizes of `int` and `long long int`.

As you wrote it, `printf` is going to the address where `b` is stored, and grabbing 8 bytes, which is (usually) the size of `long long int`. It should be grabbing only 4 bytes, which is (usually) the size of `int`.

Here is the correct program:

```cpp
#include<cstdio>
int main() {
    long long int a = 50LL;
    int b = 50;
    printf("a is %lld and b is %d", a, b);
}
```

On Microsoft Visual C++, the invalid program actually runs correctly after automatically being fixed by the compiler. Here are the warnings it generated:

```
1>main.cpp(5,12): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%lld' requires an argument of type '__int64', but variadic argument 2 has type 'int'
1>main.cpp(5,12): message : consider using '%d' in the format string
1>main.cpp(5,12): message : consider using '%I32d' in the format string
```

By the way, the initializer used for `b` is a poor choice, but perfectly valid. C++ silently performs a `narrowing conversion` that discards the high-order bits.

```cpp
int b = 50LL;  // poor form, but legal
int b = 50;    // better form
```