# nextafter vs nexttoward functions in C++ 2011?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++11, std

What is the difference between the nextafter and the nexttoward functions of the C++ 2011 standard library ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since the functions originate from C, they can't be overloaded, which means two different names for functions that do the same but have different parameter(-type)s. Here are the original signatures:

```
float nextafter(float, float);
float nexttoward(float, long double);
```

And now the standard just says there should be [a few overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) to make things nicer in C++ (`§26.8 [c.math] p11`):

> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:
>
> 1. If any argument corresponding to a `double` parameter has type `long double,` then all arguments corresponding to `double` parameters are effectively cast to `long double`.
> 2. Otherwise, if any argument corresponding to a `double` parameter has type `double` or an integer type, then all arguments corresponding to `double` parameters are effectively cast to `double`.
> 3. Otherwise, all arguments corresponding to `double` parameters are effectively cast to `float`.
>
> See also: ISO C 7.5, 7.10.2, 7.10.6.

Comment: A bit confusing to say they can't be overloaded (which isn't true), then in the next sentence to say there are overloads. In fact, C++11 has overloads, and C99 has type-generic macros.

Answer (score 6):

A crucial difference that isn't apparent from other answers is the return type. With `nextafter`, the return type is std::common_type of the `from` and `to` types. With `nexttoward`, the return type is the `from` type; since `to` is promoted to long double, its type doesn't matter. Some test code is instructive.

Output:

```
nextafter ( from, to ) vs.
nexttoward( from, to )

float       s = 1.401e-45
double      d = 4.941e-324
long double q = 3.645e-4951

----- `from` is float
nextafter ( 0.0f, s ) = 1.401e-45 float
nexttoward( 0.0f, s ) = 1.401e-45 float

nextafter ( 0.0f, d ) = 4.941e-324 double
nexttoward( 0.0f, d ) = 1.401e-45 float

nextafter ( 0.0f, q ) = 3.645e-4951 long double
nexttoward( 0.0f, q ) = 1.401e-45 float

----- `from` is double
nextafter ( 0.0,  s ) = 4.941e-324 double
nexttoward( 0.0,  s ) = 4.941e-324 double

nextafter ( 0.0,  d ) = 4.941e-324 double
nexttoward( 0.0,  d ) = 4.941e-324 double

nextafter ( 0.0,  q ) = 3.645e-4951 long double
nexttoward( 0.0,  q ) = 4.941e-324 double

----- `from` is long double
nextafter ( 0.0L, s ) = 3.645e-4951 long double
nexttoward( 0.0L, s ) = 3.645e-4951 long double

nextafter ( 0.0L, d ) = 3.645e-4951 long double
nexttoward( 0.0L, d ) = 3.645e-4951 long double

nextafter ( 0.0L, q ) = 3.645e-4951 long double
nexttoward( 0.0L, q ) = 3.645e-4951 long double
```

Code:

```
// Test nextafter and nextforward.
// nextafter's  return type is std::common_type( from, to ).
// nexttoward's return type is same as `from`;
// `to` is promoted to long double, which doesn't really have any external effect.

#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// For type(), see
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

// for demangling on non-Microsoft platforms
#ifndef _MSC_VER
    #include <cxxabi.h>
#endif

template <typename T>
std::string type()
{
    using TR = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;

    std::unique_ptr< char, void(*)(void*) > own(
        #ifndef _MSC_VER
            abi::__cxa_demangle( typeid(TR).name(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr ),
        #else
            nullptr,
        #endif
        std::free
    );

    std::string r = own != nullptr ? own.get() : typeid(TR).name();
    if (std::is_const<TR>::value)
        r += " const";
    if (std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
        r += " volatile";
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&";
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&&";
    return r;
}


template <typename T>
std::string type( T x )
{
    return type<T>();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision( 4 );
    std::cout << "nextafter ( from, to ) vs.\n"
              << "nexttoward( from, to )\n\n";

    float       s = std::nextafter( 0.0f, 1.0f );
    double      d = std::nextafter( 0.0,  1.0  );
    long double q = std::nextafter( 0.0L, 1.0L );
    std::cout << "float       s = " << s << '\n';
    std::cout << "double      d = " << d << '\n';
    std::cout << "long double q = " << q << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "----- `from` is float\n"; // Result type
    auto x1 = std::nextafter ( 0.0f, s );   // float
    auto y1 = std::nexttoward( 0.0f, s );   // float
    std::cout <<  "nextafter ( 0.0f, s ) = " << x1 << " " << type( x1 ) << '\n';
    std::cout <<  "nexttoward( 0.0f, s ) = " << y1 << " " << type( y1 ) << "\n\n";

    auto x2 = std::nextafter ( 0.0f, d );   // double
    auto y2 = std::nexttoward( 0.0f, d );   // float
    std::cout <<  "nextafter ( 0.0f, d ) = " << x2 << " " << type( x2 ) << '\n';
    std::cout <<  "nexttoward( 0.0f, d ) = " << y2 << " " << type( y2 ) << "\n\n";

    auto x3 = std::nextafter ( 0.0f, q );   // long double
    auto y3 = std::nexttoward( 0.0f, q );   // float
    std::cout <<  "nextafter ( 0.0f, q ) = " << x3 << " " << type( x3 ) << '\n';
    std::cout <<  "nexttoward( 0.0f, q ) = " << y3 << " " << type( y3 ) << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "----- `from` is double\n";
    auto x4 = std::nextafter ( 0.0,  s );   // double
    auto y4 = std::nexttoward( 0.0,  s );   // double
    std::cout <<  "nextafter ( 0.0,  s ) = " << x4 << " " << type( x4 ) << '\n';
    std::cout <<  "nexttoward( 0.0,  s ) = " << y4 << " " << type( y4 ) << "\n\n";

    auto x5 = std::nextafter ( 0.0,  d );   // double
    auto y5 = std::nexttoward( 0.0,  d );   // double
    std::cout <<  "nextafter ( 0.0,  d ) = " << x5 << " " << type( x5 ) << '\n';
    std::cout <<  "nexttoward( 0.0,  d ) = " << y5 << " " << type( y5 ) << "\n\n";

    auto x6 = std::nextafter ( 0.0,  q );   // long double
    auto y6 = std::nexttoward( 0.0,  q );   // double
    std::cout <<  "nextafter ( 0.0,  q ) = " << x6 << " " << type( x6 ) << '\n';
    std::cout <<  "nexttoward( 0.0,  q ) = " << y6 << " " << type( y6 ) << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "----- `from` is long double\n";
    auto x7 = std::nextafter ( 0.0L, s );   // long double
    auto y7 = std::nexttoward( 0.0L, s );   // long double
    std::cout <<  "nextafter ( 0.0L, s ) = " << x7 << " " << type( x7 ) << '\n';
    std::cout <<  "nexttoward( 0.0L, s ) = " << y7 << " " << type( y7 ) << "\n\n";

    auto x8 = std::nextafter ( 0.0L, d );   // long double
    auto y8 = std::nexttoward( 0.0L, d );   // long double
    std::cout <<  "nextafter ( 0.0L, d ) = " << x8 << " " << type( x8 ) << '\n';
    std::cout <<  "nexttoward( 0.0L, d ) = " << y8 << " " << type( y8 ) << "\n\n";

    auto x9 = std::nextafter ( 0.0L, q );   // long double
    auto y9 = std::nexttoward( 0.0L, q );   // long double
    std::cout <<  "nextafter ( 0.0L, q ) = " << x9 << " " << type( x9 ) << '\n';
    std::cout <<  "nexttoward( 0.0L, q ) = " << y9 << " " << type( y9 ) << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

On my laptop at least (2.3 GHz Core i9, macOS 12), for normal numbers the performance was similar (3.0e-9 sec), but if `from` is subnormal, `nexttoward` is about 11x slower than `nextafter` (5.0e-8 versus 4.5e-9 sec).

Answer (score 3):

Read man page:

> The  nexttoward()  functions  do  the  same as the nextafter() functions, except that they have a long double second argument.

Comment: I think you forgot to quote the part about how the second argument is used.

Comment: Without discussing the implications, this is not very helpful. Are there corner cases where the behavior can differ? Is there a performance overhead of converting to long double internally?