# How come cmath does not use templates and/or overloads

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, tr1, cmath

Many of the new functions brought in C++11 by TR1 have ugly C-like signatures.  For instance, quoting Boost's TR1's documentation (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_tr1/subject_list.html#boost_tr1.subject_list.special):

```
// [5.2.1.1] associated Laguerre polynomials:
double assoc_laguerre(unsigned n, unsigned m, double x);
float assoc_laguerref(unsigned n, unsigned m, float x);
long double assoc_laguerrel(unsigned n, unsigned m, long double x);
```

Obviously one would have preferred some templated implementation (which is actually the "native" signature of these functions in Boost), or at least some overloading instead of several identifiers.

I can understand that aiming at C compatibility means supporting these identifiers, but then this a nuisance for pure C++ speakers.  In addition to `<cmath>`, there could be some `<math>`, with more natural interfaces.

What is it that I am missing (besides, possibly, some previously asked questions)?

Comment: [This may be relevant.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12063878/500104)

Comment: The user base for those functions is already rather small, I guess no one thought it would be worth to require template implementations (also non-templates are much easier to maintain in form of fast inline assembly stuff)

Comment: @Xeo Thanks, I completely missed the paragraphs 3, 4, and 5 from [5.2.1]: they do require that overloads be added for `float` and `long double` based on the `double` signatures (the one with the appropriate name).

Comment: Also see Jonathan Wakely's [Why `<cstdlib>` is more complicated than you might think](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/29/why-cstdlib-is-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/) from the Red Hat blogs. Wakely is one of GCC's C++ standard library maintainers. I think `<math.h>` vs `<cmath>` is a much more interesting case study because C++ requires the three overloads for many functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about Boost, but all of the standard functions in
`<cmath>` have overloads for the three standard types, so you
have e.g.:

```
double cos(double);
float cos(float);
long double cos(long double);
```

in place of C's:

```
double cos(double);
float cosf(float);
long double cosl(long double);
```

I'm not quite sure why you want a function template instead of
overloads.  For most mathematic functions, no generic
implementation is possible; a correct implementation will depend
on precision, rounding rules, etc. which are different for each
type.  So the alternative would be a template function without
a generic implementation, and three specializations.  And what
does that buy you over the "simpler" overloaded functions?