# Is there a typeid for references?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, type-conversion

I am looking for a way to obtain the name of a type, similar to `typeid` but for references. According to [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), `typeid` removes the reference.

> If type is a reference type, the result refers to the referenced type.

I am looking for code similar to

```
int x = 5;
int & y = x;
wcout << typeid( y ).name();
```

but whose output is "int &" rather than "int".

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but remember that the string returned by [`type_info::name`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) is *implementation specific*. If you change compiler the output might not be `int` at all.

Comment: How would you use it?

Comment: As for your problem, that's how references work, they reference something else so every time you use a reference it's the same as using what it references.

Comment: @n.m.: In a cycle where a C++ program inspects a C++ program and writes another C++ program. So, implementation dependent is OK as long as it has the references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/4040331) for the C++11 way to do it - it involves using type_traits. Here is the relevant section of code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#   include <cxxabi.h>
#endif
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

template <class T>
std::string
type_name()
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type TR;
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> own
           (
#ifndef _MSC_VER
                abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(TR).name(), nullptr,
                                           nullptr, nullptr),
#else
                nullptr,
#endif
                std::free
           );
    std::string r = own != nullptr ? own.get() : typeid(TR).name();
    if (std::is_const<TR>::value)
        r += " const";
    if (std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
        r += " volatile";
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&";
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&&";
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The only portable way of doing this that I know of is to use [Boost.TypeIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_typeindex.html)

```
std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(x)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(y)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
```

Prints

```
int
int&
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2fc513f587d5798)

Comment: Boost.TypeIndex did not give me exactly what I needed. The references came out adorned with "_ptr64".

Comment: @Hector You got that from the `y` shown in the question? The only time I remember seeing `__ptr64` was when I was trying to figure out the return types of some member functions of the `vector<bool>` specialization on MSVC. Turns out those are [native pointer types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985900.aspx) used by that compiler, so it really is part of the type name. I'm curious to see how you came across these, can you create a test case?

Comment: `boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr< struct A & >().pretty_name()` produces `struct A & __ptr64` in Visual Studio 2013 update 4.

Comment: @Hector Thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can avoid that because as the link above explains, that is the type used by the compiler. The `__ptr64` does disappear if you target x86 instead of x64. Another quirk I discovered is that MSVC's type name includes the calling convention. The second print statement of [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3100d67cb35a6f49) produces `void (__cdecl A::*)(void) __ptr64`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following work-around to be very useful. I let the compiler fail with an error message telling me the actual type. To use the original poster's use case:

```
#include <type_traits>

int x = 5;
int & y = x;

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(y), bool>::value, "");
```

clang, starting from version 8.0.0, outputs the following:

```
error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_same<int &, bool>::value'
```

You may find a working example in the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/43ff85Ko5).

- Note 1: Obviously, if the type happens to be `bool`, the static assertion won't fail.
- Note 2: I understand that this solution doesn't print the type, but it might be sufficient in some cases as it was for me.