# What is the type of new int[M][N]?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, dynamic, multidimensional-array

According to `typeid(array).name()` it is `PAN_i` in G++ 4.8.4. I know `P` means pointer and `i` means int, but what type is `A` and why is there only second dimension - `N` - and not the first - `M`.

What should I type instead of auto in `auto array = new int[M][N]`?

Is there a way to assign `array` to `int**`?

Another issue is M and N must be compile-time constants. If they are not, I guess my only option is [the dynamic C++03 2D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936702/1459339).

Comment: It would help knowing the compiler, for `name` returns a string that is implementation defined, see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name

Comment: The compiler is GCC 4.8.2. It is the same in MinGW 4.9.2.

Comment: I don't think that you can do `new int[M][N]` to begin with (although, maybe in C++11 you can). But you can declare `typedef int[M][N] MyArray_t` and then use `new MyArray_t` (assuming that `M` and `N` are constants). In any case, in C++ you may as well use `vector<vector<int>>`. Otherwise, if you still insist on using a native (C-style) array, then the type in this case should be `int**`.

Comment: @barakmanos I think it is OK. And only `N` has to be a compile time constant.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c . Moreover, you are asking three different things in a question with a title the does not cover all of them.

Comment: @juanchopanza: As far as I recall, you need to allocate the first dimension (`int** array = new int*[M]`), and then for each entry in the array, allocate the second dimension (`array[i] = new int[N]`).

Comment: @barakmanos It is a C++11 only feature. The `typedef int[M][N] MyArray_t` throws me  `error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
 typedef int[2][3] MyArray_t;`.

Comment: Sorry, should be `typedef int MyArray_t[M][N]`. BTW, the terminology "throws an error" (more accurately "throws an exception") is reserved for runtime errors (those that occur when you execute your program). The error that you're referring to is a **compilation** error. It's not just nit-picking, knowing the differences between compile-time and runtime is an important part of your general comprehension.

Comment: @barakmanos Re. "As far as I recall", that is doing something else.

Comment: @juanchopanza: "As far as I can sense" you are patronizing, so this conversation is terminated.

Comment: @barakmanos I am not. I am saying the thing you are describing is a different thing to `new int[M][N]`.

Comment: @Slazer `new int[M][N]?` is valid in C++03 too. Of course, `N` has to be a compile time constant.

Comment: @juanchopanza: OK. I'm pretty sure that the `typedef` syntax is identical (in terms of compilation, hence obviously in terms of runtime). The other allocation method that I've suggested would indeed yield a different memory structure during runtime (assuming that `new int[M][N]` is "compilable" (I thought it wasn't, but if you insist then I take your word for it)).

Comment: @skypjack It is not a duplicate. I know `typeid(t).name()`. But its  does not answer the question `What should I type instead of auto in auto array = new int[M][N]?`.

Comment: Its not a duplicate. I needed to interpret the output of `typeid(x).name()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the type of new int[M][N]?

The type is pointer to length `N` array of int<sup>1</sup>, or

```
int (*)[N]
```

If you think of what a `new[]` expression does, it initializes an array of a length given at runtime and returns a pointer to the first element of that array. So the type of

```
new T[M]
```

is `T*`. In the 2D case, you can think of `T` as being `int[N]`. So each element of the array is a itself array, and `new` returns a pointer to its first element. This may be a clearer way of expressing it:

```
typedef int ArrayN[N];

auto array = new ArrayN[M];
```

---

<sup>1 And in C++, the dimensions if C-style arrays have to be compile time constants, meaning `N` has to be a constant expression</sup>

Comment: You may also want to suggest the use of `typedef int MyArray_t[M][N]`, and perhaps also recommend the use of `vector<vector<int>>` in this case.

Comment: I have to use `bool**` to represent the structure.

Comment: @barakmanos I might do. But I don't prefer to stick to answering one quesiton per post, because they should only be asking one question.

Comment: This is answered. I am going to ask the other questions separately.

Comment: @barakmanos I added a `typedef` example, but only with a 1D array, because that is the type of the elements of the array created with the new expression.

Comment: Why N has to be constant expression and M does not?

Comment: @Slazer The dimension `M` is the length of the dynamically allocated array. That array contains C-style arrays. And in C++ those need a size known at compile time.