# Can an lvalue reference non-type template parameter be inferred?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, lvalue

I have the following code, which I cannot get to work:

```
struct foo {};
foo foo1 = {};

template <foo& F>
class FooClass {};

template <foo& F>
void foobar(FooClass<F> arg) {
}

int main() {
    FooClass<foo1> f;
    foobar(f);
}
```

The error is:

> main.cpp:14:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foobar'
>
> note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure : deduced non-type template argument does not have the same type as the its corresponding template parameter ('foo' vs 'foo &')

Is it at all **possible** to infer *lvalue* reference template parameters? If so, how should it be done?

Comment: The error message even contains a typo xD "as the its". Probably not a very common scenario. But I doubt that two compilers get it wrong? (It's rejected by both gcc6.0 and clang3.9)

Comment: Isn't it that template arguments must be constant expressions...?

Comment: @101010 Since the argument is a global variable, the "address" of that variable is a constant expression. Or rather, it has a fixed symbol name that can be used to instantiate the template. Similarly, references to variables of static storage duration can be used as template arguments.

Comment: This is probably [temp.deduct.type]p17, but it seems overly restrictive in this case: The (observable) type of `foo1` as an expression is `foo` and therefore does not match the type `foo&` of the template parameter `F` exactly. Might be a defect in the Standard.

Comment: Fwiw, my type_name function (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/576911) reports the type of `f` as `FooClass<foo1>` on both clang and gcc.  This represents independently written versions of `__cxa_demangle` as specified here:  http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling

Comment: VS-2015 reports `f` has type `class FooClass<&struct foo foo1>`.  **And** it successfully compiles this example.

Comment: @101010 see [tem.arg.nontype]/1 . The wording is that the argument must be a "constant expression [...] except that the `&` may be omitted if the template-parameter is a reference"  . This is rather cumbersome but it's trying to saying that you can use the name of any object with static storage duration (because applying `&` to such an object would produce a constant expression)

Comment: @dyp Ts ts, you should've checked the database immediately! :P

Comment: @molf: *"... Easy to fix, right? Just prepend an `&`:..."*??? How could prepending `F` with `&` (i.e. turning it into a *pointer* expression) possibly fix anything here?

Comment: @AnT Yes, I realised that after writing it.

Comment: @Columbo I did, but obviously not thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is precisely covered by [**CWG 2091**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2091):

> According to 14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type] paragraph 17,
>
> > If `P` has a form that contains `<i>`, and if the type of the corresponding value of `A` differs from the type of `i`, deduction
> >     fails.
>
> This gives the wrong result for an example like:
>
> ```
> template<int &> struct X;
> template<int &N> void f(X<N>&);
> int n;
> void g(X<n> &x) { f(x); }
> ```
>
> Here, `P` is `X<N>`, which contains `<i>`. The type of `i` is `int&`.
>   The corresponding value from `A` is `n`, which is a glvalue of type
>   `int`. Presumably this should be valid.
>
> I think this rule means to say something like,
>
> > If `P` has a form that contains `<i>`, and the type of `i` differs from the type of the corresponding template parameter of the template
> >     named by the enclosing *simple-template-id*, deduction fails.

As noted by @dyp, [[temp.deduct.type]/17](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#17) should be more permissive. In your example, the argument in `FooClass<F>` (`F`) does not have reference type - it's an lvalue of type `foo`. The template parameter of `FooClass` is a reference. The DR was resolved last year.

Comment: Is there a way to workaround the issue and make this example work?