# How to make reference variable to boost::bimap.left?

Tags: c++, boost, types, boost-bimap

I'm using `boost::bimap` to map integers to strings:

```
typedef boost::bimap<int, std::string> ParamIDStrings;
typedef ParamIDStrings::value_type id_pair;
extern const ParamIDStrings paramIDStrings;
```

I'm trying to create reference variables so I can write code like:

```
paramIDStringsByID.at(5);
// Instead of having to remember which side is which:
paramIDStrings.left.at(5);
```

But I'm having a hard time interpreting the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/reference/bimap_reference.html), to understand of what type `bimap::left` is.

I tried:

```
// Compiler throws error: invalid use of template-name 'boost::bimaps::bimap' without an argument list
boost::bimaps::bimap::left &paramIDStringsByID = paramIDStrings.left;

// Compiler throws error: 'paramIDStrings' does not name a type
paramIDStrings::left_map &paramIDStringsByID = paramIDStrings.left;

// Compiler throws error: invalid initialization of reference of type boost::bimaps::bimap<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::left_map
boost::bimaps::bimap<int,std::string>::left_map &cParamIDStringsByID = cParamIDStrings.left;
```

Comment: Have you tried `auto &` and not care?

Comment: @nwp Whoa, thank you. Now I know what `auto` is useful for. If you make an answer I will accept it. Still, would be good to know what the actual type is, if only to learn how the heck to read these confusing Boost docs.

Comment: how about `boost::bimaps::bimap<int,std::string>::left_map & lmap` ?

Comment: @DevanshMohanKaushik I tried it but it didn't work (I added the error message to my question).

Comment: that's strange. Because `boost::bimap< int,std::string > mymap;`    `boost::bimaps::bimap<int,std::string>::left_map & lmap= mymap.left;` works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `auto &` to let the compiler do the work for you.
If you want to know the type that gets deduced you can use one of the tricks [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617848/3484570) to make the compiler tell you.

Answer (score 0):

`boost/bimap/bimap.hpp` has a typedef for this: `left_map` and `right_map`. So you can do:

```
paramIDStrings::left_map &paramIDStringsByID = paramIDStrings.left;
```