# See type of C++ auto keyword in AndroidStudio

Tags: c++, android-studio, ide

Is there a way to see the type of a variable declared with `auto` in Android Studio? In Eclipse you can see this by mouse over the `auto` keyword.

For example:

```
auto foo = 2.0F; // auto == float
auto bar = std::sqrt(25.0);  // auto == double
```

Edit:
I am looking for an IDE solution, in this case Android studio. I would like Android Studio to tell me what is the deduced type of `auto`. Just like Eclipse shows you when you mouse over an `auto` keyword in code.

Comment: IMHO this is an abuse of `auto`, but not really relevant I know.

Comment: @Bathsheba I kinda like it, especially when combining ints, unsigned ints and such. With auto I don't get any implicit casts and with mouse over I can see what type the result will be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to print a variable's type in standard C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c)

Comment: @RichardCritten Not really. I am looking for an IDE solution, not a run time solution.