# When i use auto bi = 123456789, in C++, is it always assigned as an int?

Tags: c++, gcc

If i want bi to be an `long int`, isn't possible to use auto because it always assign as int?

Comment: Why do you think it "assigns as int"?

Comment: If you wrap it in quotes, it definitely won't be an int. It will be a `char const*` (I think). --- You can check the types of your variables like mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c)

Comment: If you specifically want it to be a `long`, why not just say so to the compiler `long bi = `?

Comment: A string is a string. C++ have no automatic conversion between numbers in strings and actual numbers.

Comment: The keywords you're looking for are "integer literals".  There are a bunch of suffixes you can use to control type.

Comment: Your question is C++, and probably C++11, so this is just a remark concerning C.  `auto`  in C denotes a storage class -- on the stack. Omitting a variable's type in C89 defaulted the type to int, so that `auto i;`  declared an `int` variable with automatic storage duration. If a compiler lets you get away with assigning a pointer to an int (like my gcc 5.4.0 does), then `auto i = "123456789";` declares (and defines, and initializes with an address) *an `int` variable.*

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson You re right! I just edited now, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some options:

```
auto bi = "123456789";          // const char*
auto bi2 = 12345;               // int
auto bi3 = 123456789;           // int (when int is 32 bits or more )
auto bi4a = 123456789L;         // long
auto bi4b = 178923456789L;      // long long! (L suffix asked for long, but got long long so that the number can fit)
auto bi5a = 123456789LL;        // long long
auto bi5b = 123456784732899;    // long long (on my system it is long long, but might be different on ILP64; there is would just be an int)
auto bi6 = 123456789UL;         // unsigned long
auto bi7 = 123456789ULL;        // unsigned long long
```

All of the examples above depend on the system that you use.

In the standard, in `[lex.icon]` *Table 5 — Types of integer literals* is referenced:

> The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list
>   in Table 5 in which its value can be represented.

If we look at the table for **decimal literals** we see that even the effects of the `U` and `L` suffixes depend upon what size can be accommodated:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer. You could go a step further and add an example of `long long`.

Comment: also longlong (ll) and unsigned long long (ull).

Comment: I'm trying to find an SO question where the table is mentioned from the standard that describes how the type is selected for the literal.

Comment: @flatmouse: You have to go down to the C standard to find range values.

Comment: Note that `bi5b` would be just `int` (i.e. `long long` would be incorrect) on an ILP64 architecture; see (http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/64bit.html).