# Why are the typeids of int, int&, and int&& same?

Tags: c++, type-safety, type-systems, typesafe, typeid

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << typeid(int).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(int&).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(int&&).name() << endl;
}
```

The output is:

> int
>
> int
>
> int

My compiler is clang 5.0.

**Why are the typeids of int, int&, and int&& same?**

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/1460794

Comment: `typeid` ignores top-level qualifiers.

Comment: Not the issue, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.