# How do I find out what type the elements of my 3D container are?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, return-value, decltype

If I have some 3D container, which can be the combination of any containing types out there.
and I have to write a generic function which receives this container as an argument, and has to return a 2D container (a matrix) that is the same type as the elements of the 3D container.

For expample, the 3D container received:

```
std::vector<std::deque<std::deque<int>>> 3D;
```

The returned type:

```
std::deque<std::deque<int>>
```

How can I achieve this, and make the return type generic and dependent on the multidimensional container that has been received?
Lets say I have a generic function that receives a 3D container, and has to return the same type that the 3D container contains. For example: my function is like this:

```
template<typename 3D>  
 auto Function(3D Knt)-> decltype(0+Knt[0]){
// randome code
decltype(0+Knt[0]) K;
// randome code
return K;
}
```

Will this cause any errors?

Comment: Standard containers declare a member `value_type` type for this purpose.

Comment: I'm confused: You seem to know about `decltype`, so you should be able to work how to get the type.

Comment: Yess, I know of it, but i dont know how to target the element, or the element of the element of the 3D container. I tried it like this: auto Function(kontainer 3D) ->decltype(0+3D[0]){}
but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `3D` is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `typedef` inside all STL containers that gives you that information. Of course, you can forget about printing that type, but you can use it. (you can [play RTTI games to print the name of the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c), but it's compiler dependent and requiring that is an indicator of bad design).

So, if you have:

```
std::deque<int> myArray;
```

then you can use

```
std::deque<int>::value_type one_element;
```

and now `one_element` will be of type `int`.

On the other hand, you can use `myArray` itself to extract that information like this:

```
decltype(myArray)::value_type one_element;
```

and again, `one_element` is of type `int`.

Edit: I'm not sure I understand the problem. But if you're **sure** that this is a 3D container, then the deepest element type can be extracted as follows:

If you have:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > 3dArray;
```

then

```
decltype(3dArray)::value_type::value_type::value_type one_element;
```

will be of type `int`. If you use this on an array that's not 3D, it won't compile.

Comment: Lets say I have a generic function that recives a 3D container, and has to return the same type that the 3D container containes. For example: my function is like this:
'template <typename 3D>'
'auto Function(3D Knt)-> decltype(0+Knt[0]){'
'// randome code'
'decltype(0+Knt[0]) K;'
'// randome code'
'return K;'
'}'

Is this alright? Will this work?

Comment: @Nane Two things: 1. Add this to your question, I can't understand here. 2. Try it before asking "will this work" and ask about the problem when it doesn't, not about whether it's gonna work.

Comment: I added it. I am sorry for bothering you, this is basically how my function looks like (simplified), and I did try it beforehand, but the compiler is reporting errors (a lot of them, and some point to this part), and I just want to know if this is a proper way to do this or if I made a mistake because I never used it before and my knowledge of its use is a bit shaky. Not trying to be lazy, I am just a beginner.

Comment: @Nane I'm not familiar with the `auto` return, but I gave you how to extract the inner-most type from a 3D array. I gotta go sleep, so I'll continue tomorrow. Try and see whether you can get what you want with this information. Good luck!