# printf format based on data type

Tags: c++, types, printf

I have a templated buffer class with a simple printing function.

```
template <typename valueType, typename sumType, int N>
class IM_buffer
{
public:
    IM_buffer()
        : bufferValues(), numValues(-1), currentSum() { }

    void record(valueType sample)
    {
        // Set buffer index to be recorded
        numValues++;

        // Get memory location for oldest element in buffer
        valueType& oldest = bufferValues[modIdx(numValues)];

        // Add the input value to the current sum and take away the value being replaced
        currentSum += sample - oldest;

        // And now do the actual replacement in the same memory location
        oldest = sample;
    }

    valueType   getCurrent()            { return bufferValues[modIdx(numValues)];           }
    valueType   getNthPrev(int Nprev)   { return bufferValues[modIdx(numValues-Nprev)];     }
    sumType     getCurrentSum()         { return currentSum;                                }
    double      getAvg()                { return (double) currentSum / MIN(numValues+1, N); }
    int         getNumValues()          { return numValues+1;                               }
    int         getBufferSize()         { return N;                                         }

    void printBuff()
    {
        for (int ii=0; ii<N; ii++)
        {
            // if it's an integer type I need:
            printf("bufferValues[%2d]=%4d\n",ii,bufferValues[ii]);
            // but if it's a floating point type I need:
            printf("bufferValues[%2d]=%8g\n",ii,bufferValues[ii]);
        }
    }

    void clear()
    {
        for (int ii=0; ii<N; ii++)
            bufferValues[ii] = (valueType) 0.0;
        numValues = 0;
        currentSum = (sumType) 0.0;
    }

private:
    valueType bufferValues[N];
    int numValues;
    sumType currentSum;

    int modIdx(int a) { return (a % N + N) % N; }
};
```

However, the format string of the `printf` should depend on what the data type is (e.g. int, vs. float, vs double). I've seen discussions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c) but I don't really want to print out the data type, I just need to change the `printf` format string based on the data type. Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to implement some condition logic to select the right `printf`?

Comment: That's one of the nice things about C++ streams like `std::cout`, it can handle different types without fixed-format specifiers like for `printf`. In short, don't use `printf` in C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can't remember the exact conflict, but `#include <iostream>` broke some other aspect of the code so that's why I was using `printf` - a smaller set of include headers.

Comment: Then you are doing something you should not do. You should ask about that problem in a new question.

Comment: And using `printf` is going to be even worse if you use a non-builtin type as the template argument. What happens if you try to use `std::string` or perhaps your own custom class? With `std::cout` there is an overloaded `<<` function for `std::string` already, and you can easily create one for custom classes and types. You can't do that with `printf` really.

Comment: Unfortunately the bulk of the code is not mine to be changing so I'm not sure that I can get around not being able to use streams in this particular case. Luckily, I will not be dealing with any non-builtin types for the problem at hand.

Comment: There is a solution, one that I don't really recommend since there are nicer ways to do it in C++, and it is to use function overloading. You can have a private static member function that takes an `int` as argument and prints using `"%d"`. Then one overload for `double` which uses `"%g"`, etc. What I really recommend is that you fix the underlying problem that you can include `<iostream>` (are you doing `using namespace std;`? [Perhaps that's the the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), because of name clashes?)

Comment: I was thinking about function overloading - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Concerning the `<iostream>` problem, I am not doing `using namespace std;`. I actually just tried doing the `cout` approach instead and it worked. I guess whoever had broken things related to `<iostream>` unbroke them and didn't tell me. Sorry for leading things in circles. If you post the original suggestion as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned in the comments, you should use `std::cout` that has overloads for all built in types. However, if you really insist on using `printf`, you can try the following hack:

```
#include <typeinfo>  // for typeid

std::string printfCmd("I wish to print this: ");
// int myVar = 69;  // uncomment to change var type to int
char myVar = 'd';
if (typeid(int) == typeid(myVar)) {
    printfCmd += "%d";
} else if (typeid(char) == typeid(myVar)) {
    printfCmd += "%c";
} else {
    // some warning/error
}

printf(printfCmd.c_str(), myVar);
```

It is not a good solution, use it only if you really have to.

Comment: You can do it slightly less hackily with templates. But yeah.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the C++ overloaded insertion operators, you can write your own overloaded function:

```
void print(int i) {
    printf("%4d",i);
}

void print(double d) {
    printf("%8g",d);
}
```

etc.

Now you can call `print` from your `printBuff` function when needed:

```
printf("bufferValues["%2d] =",ii);
print(bufferValues[ii]);
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which may or may not be better than the other solutions depending on your situation, is to use templates to template the format specifiers at compile-time based on type.

TL;DR example programs (linked below):

- https://godbolt.org/z/3Yz6be67a - General idea
- https://godbolt.org/z/fjcrzY87a - Omitting field width and precision
- https://godbolt.org/z/h9cGY1Ps1 - Platform-independence with `cinttypes`
- https://godbolt.org/z/cnMd818Mo - Compile-time checking for mistakes (also probably the most concise example)

Anyways:

```
template <typename T> static const char *outFormat = ""; // pick a default.
template <> const char *outFormat<float> = "%8.4f";
template <> const char *outFormat<double> = "%8.4lf";
template <> const char *outFormat<long double> = "%8.4Lf";
template <> const char *outFormat<char> = "%c";
```

And use them like this, for example:

```
typedef float some_api_type; // some external libraries unknown type

void printAPIValue (some_api_type value) {
    printf(outFormat<some_api_type>, value);
    printf("\n");
}

// or, for example, printing an stl container...
template <typename Container> void printValues (const Container &c) {
    using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
    printf("[ ");
    for (auto i = c.cbegin(); i != c.cend(); ++ i) {
        printf(outFormat<value_type>, *i);
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

So, e.g. [this program](https://godbolt.org/z/3Yz6be67a):

```
some_api_type value = 4;
std::vector<float> floats = { 1.0f, 1.1f, -2.345f };
std::vector<char> chars = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };

printAPIValue(value);
printValues(floats);
printValues(chars);
```

Would produce this output:

```
  4.0000
[   1.0000   1.1000  -2.3450 ]
[ h e l l o ]
```

---

There are many various forms of the above, so you'd have to do something that works well in your situation. For example:

- I specified the `%` and field width / precision for convenience. You could remove all that and construct it as needed, in which case using an `std::string` might save you some typing later. [This program](https://godbolt.org/z/fjcrzY87a):

  ```
    template <typename T> static string outFormat;
    template <> const string outFormat<float> = "f";
    template <> const string outFormat<int> = "d";

    // graceful handling of unsupported types omitted.
    template <typename Container> void printValues (const Container &c) {
        using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
        int index = 0;
        printf("list with format %s:\n", outFormat<value_type>.c_str());
        for (auto i = c.cbegin(); i != c.cend(); ++ i, ++ index) {
            string format = "item[%d] = %10" + outFormat<value_type> + "\n";
            printf(format.c_str(), index, *i);
        }
    }

    int main () {
        std::vector<float> floats = { 1.0f, 1.1f, -2.345f };
        std::vector<int> ints = { -1, 1, -2, 9 };
        printValues(floats);
        printValues(ints);
    }
  ```

  Outputs:

  ```
    list with format f:
    item[0] =   1.000000
    item[1] =   1.100000
    item[2] =  -2.345000
    list with format d:
    item[0] =         -1
    item[1] =          1
    item[2] =         -2
    item[3] =          9
  ```
- You can also make use of *cinttypes* (C's *inttypes.h*) for some platform-independent stuff, e.g. [this program](https://godbolt.org/z/h9cGY1Ps1):

  ```
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <cinttypes> // types and PRI* sized format specifiers

    template <typename T> static const char *hexFormat = "<unsupported type>";
    template <> const char *hexFormat<uint8_t> = "0x%02" PRIx8;
    template <> const char *hexFormat<uint16_t> = "0x%04" PRIx16;
    template <> const char *hexFormat<uint32_t> = "0x%08" PRIx32;
    template <> const char *hexFormat<uint64_t> = "0x%016" PRIx64;

    template <typename UIntValue> void printHex (UIntValue value) {
        printf(hexFormat<UIntValue>, value);
        printf("\n");
    }

    int main () {
        printHex((size_t)0xABCD1234);
        printHex(9U);
        printHex(9UL);
        printHex((unsigned char)'!');
        printHex(9.0);
    }
  ```

  On a 64-bit platform, that might output:

  ```
    0x00000000abcd1234
    0x00000009
    0x0000000000000009
    0x21
    <unsupported type>
  ```
- You have various options to enforce that supported types are used, I'm not going to list them, use your imagination. But; since you're using templates, you can get some compile-time checks if you want. For example, [this program](https://godbolt.org/z/cnMd818Mo), using `static_assert`:

  ```
    #include <cstdio>

    template <typename T> static constexpr const char *format = nullptr;
    template <> constexpr const char * format<short> = "%hd\n";
    template <> constexpr const char * format<int> = "%d\n";
    template <> constexpr const char * format<long> = "%ld\n";

    template <typename Value> void print (Value value) {
        static_assert(format<Value> != nullptr, "Unsupported type.");
        printf(format<Value>, value);
    }

    int main () {
        print<short>(1);
        print<int>(1);
        print<float>(1);  // <-- compilation will fail here
        print<long>(1);
    }
  ```

  Will fail to compile that `print<float>` line with:

  ```
    error: static assertion failed: Unsupported type.
  ```

  Which can help you catch errors.

---

There's probably a lot more to say about all of this but I'm sick of typing and need to get back to work. Hopefully this is helpful to somebody.