# Constexpr typeid to order types

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, c++17, constexpr

I'd like to sort a parameterpack so that two instances of a template instantiated with the same parameters in different order become the same type.

Sorting I can probably manage the hard part is to make the incoming types comparable at compile time.

Is there something akin to `typeid` that is `constexpr` and can map any type to an object with `constexpr <`?

Comment: Probably better if you give your best example pseudo code, to clarify what you mean.

Comment: I've seen an exact duplicate somewhere and will find it in a moment. TL;DR: Impossible in standard C++, but there is a portable enough solution: you can extract type name as a constexpr string from `template <typename T> constexpr const char *foo(){return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;}` (or `__FUNCSIG__` on MSVC), and compare those strings.

Comment: Aha, found it: [How to order types at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723974/how-to-order-types-at-compile-time)

Comment: Nicely done, @HolyBlackCat.  I knew that existed somewhere and was not succeeding at finding it.

Comment: You can easily compare two packs for set equality (C++ types are apparently of metaclass `Eq`), but ordering types is not trivial (no trivial `Ord`.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So, the most portable answer is to wait until reflection is in the Standard.