# C++ "Reflection" for bit field structs

Tags: c++, reflection, bit-fields

I am looking for a way to do "reflection" in C++ over a bit-field struct like this:

```
 struct Bits {
    uint32_t opCode : 5;
    uint32_t header : 3;
    uint32_t source : 5;
    uint32_t destination : 5;
    uint32_t offset : 13;
 };
```

My goal is to be able to get things like:

1. All member names as std::string list ex. "opCode", "header", etc...
2. The underlying typename as a std::string ex. "uint32_t"
3. The number of bits for each field as a std::int list ex. 5,3,5,5,13

with *minimal hand-coding, macros, or boilerplate code*. These values should in principal, be able to be determined at compile-time, though it is not a necessity.

After reading through [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41453/8245487), it is clear there are some "reflection" capabilities provided by libraries outside of standard C++. Looking into things like [Precise and Flat Reflection](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get), [Ponder](https://billyquith.github.io/ponder/docs/index.html), [Boost Reflect](http://bytemaster.github.io/boost_reflect/), and even [Boost Hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html), I have not found support for something like this.

I have already found a [way to get the member names and typenames of a non-bitfield struct using Boost Hana](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50611863/8245487) [this achieves #1 and #2 for ordinary structs], and there is a [way to get the member names of a bitfield struct using Boost Fusion](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/314#issuecomment-398865014) [this achieves #1 for bitfield structs], though it is a custom code solution.

Alternatively, manually flattening/decaying the struct to a single unit32_t member struct like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2468708/8245487):

```
struct BitsFlattened{
  uint32_t message;
}
```

with manually coded getters and setters for the appropriate members is also a possibility, where getters might expose the information by their name ex. getopCode05(), getheader69().

Comment: I am ok with using open-source libraries, metaprogramming, Boost, etc. I guess I shouldn't write "native C++". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Actually, it might just be easier to develop a custom macro for this...

Comment: To solve this, I ended up developing a custom macro. Boost Hana and other libraries may one day be able to support this - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/409) on adding generalized annotations to Boost Hana - this would allow one to do Reflection on any sort of struct, whether they had default values, were arrays, or were bitfields, and so on...