# What is the actual result type of std::chrono::duration::count function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

What is the actual result type of `std::chrono::duration::count` function like in the following case:

```
std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count();
```

It [seems](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count) like it is some `rep` type but what is it actually? I need to know the exact type to pass it to some other languages. Can I just cast it to `long long`, for example?

Comment: According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) it would seem to be a `signed integer type of at least 45 bits`.

Comment: It says you are casting to "std::chrono::milliseconds"

Answer (score 4):

The type is `std::chrono::milliseconds::rep`.  You can inspect this type with [a function that prints out types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/576911).  For example:

```
#include "type_name.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << type_name<std::chrono::milliseconds::rep>() << '\n';
}
```

For me (and probably for you too), this outputs:

```
long long
```

Comment: Ok, what should I do then? I need to pass this result type to another language so I need to know at least how large it is.

Comment: Just be careful of this, the *proper* type is the first one given, `std:chrono:milliseconds:rep`. Using `long long` may well be unportable if, for example, an implementation wants to provide enough bits to measure milliseconds from the big bang to the heat death :-) As to passing it to another language, if only there were some common representation. I think, if I were to invent this, I'd call it, I don't know, something like "text" :-) Note the smileys, I'm not intending to offend.

Comment: `sizeof` is the C++ way to get the number of bytes a type or variable takes.  And text is a good idea for passing among languages unless it is known a-priori that the two languages share the same binary representation for the type.

Answer (score 2):

From doc, `count` returns `rep` type which comes from `template<class Rep, class Period = std::ratio<1>> class duration;`

Moreover,

```
std::chrono::milliseconds   duration</*signed integer type of at least 45 bits*/, std::milli>
```

So it is implementation specific.

Comment: This is why `auto` is such a good idea, sometimes you just shouldn't have to care :-)

Comment: Ok, what should I do then? I need to pass this result type to another language so I need to know at least how large it is.

Comment: It depends. You might have code dependent of rep `type` to give appropriate type, or use your type and "convert" result to your type (as `std::int64_t`) (care with signed overflow :/).