# Unexpected behaviour of std::move on T* type in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, typeid, value-categories

I have below code snippet where i declare a variable called `pval` which is attempting to derive `T&&` on a `T*` [ with `T` being `int` ]. As per type information [ decoded using abi ] the type derived is `int*`.

But when I compare the `int*` type with `decltype(pval)` it returns zero rather than 1 which means it treats `pval` as different type other than `int*`. So which one is the wrong `pval` being `int*` as reported by `typeid` or `is_same` which indicates comparison as false.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<typeinfo>
#include<cxxabi.h>
#include<type_traits>

using namespace std;

std::string classname(const std::type_info& info)
{
    int status;
    char* rslt=abi::__cxa_demangle(info.name(),0,0,&status);
    std::string result(rslt);
    free(rslt);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int* ptr = new int(10);
    decltype(std::move(ptr)) pval = std::move(ptr);
    cout << classname(typeid(pval)) << endl;             // as per typeid information the type of pval is int*.

    bool isSame = is_same<decltype(pval), int*>::value;  // What then is the pval not same as int* as per is_same ? 
    cout << "isSame status = " << isSame << endl;
    cout << is_same<int*, int*>::value << endl;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: sorry had missed it , will do so going forward

Comment: Thank you burnabyRails:), I have marked all my questions now with a correct/most accurate answer that helped me.

Comment: Glad to see that you have. You have earned a few reps and the scholar badge! Just in case, there is no need to overdo it. Accepted answer should resolve your question basically. Anyway, that is your call. I am going to remove all my comments here soon.

Comment: Yes, most of the answers have solved my problems. Yup, I got more points and reputations thx!! enjoying my hat ..... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviors of `decltype` and `typeid` are different.

The exact type of `pval` is `int* &&`, i.e. an rvalue-reference to `int*`. (That's why `std::is_same` returns `false` when comparing it with the type of `int*`.) According to the behavior of [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/decltype),

> if the value category of expression is xvalue, then decltype yields T&&;

And what `std::move(ptr)` returns is an [xvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue).

> The following expressions are xvalue expressions:
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`;

Then given `decltype(std::move(ptr)) pval`, the type of `pval` would be `int* &&`.

On the other hand, the behavior of [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) is different.

> Refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type `type`. If `type` is a reference type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the referenced type.

That means the `std::type_info` object returned by `typeid(pval)` will refer to the referenced type, i.e. `int*`, not `int* &&`.

---

<sup>BTW: What [`std::type_info::name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) returns is implementation defined.</sup>

Comment: understood my classname function itself is not accurate then as indicated by below which makes things much more clear and explicit. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

The `__cxa_demangle()` function doesn't give you reliable (or any?) information about const and reference qualifiers. Try this instead of your `classname()` function:

```
template <typename T, bool WithCVCorrections = true>
std::string type_name()
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type TR;

    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> own(
    abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(TR).name(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr),
        std::free
    );
    std::string r = (own != nullptr) ? own.get() : typeid(TR).name();
    if (WithCVCorrections) {
        if (std::is_const<TR>::value)
            r += " const";
        if (std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
            r += " volatile";
        if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
            r += "&";
        else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
            r += "&&";
    }
    return r;
}
```

... which is based on Howard Hinnant's code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/1593077). Obvious caveat: This will only work for some compilers (not MSVC).

Comment: worked like magic , thx for the help einpoklum i learnt something today about what is not covered by typeid :)