# Segfault when not specifying return type of lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have this example code:

```
// Copyright 2019 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f(std::function<const std::string&()> fn) {
  std::cout << "in f" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "str: " << fn() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::string str = "a";

  auto fn1 = [&]() { return str; };
  auto fn2 = [&]() { const std::string& str2 = str; return str2; };
  auto fn3 = [&]() -> const std::string& { return str; };

  std::cout << "in main" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "fn1: " << fn1() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "fn2: " << fn2() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "fn3: " << fn3() << std::endl;

  f(fn1);  // Segfaults
  f(fn2);  // Also segfaults
  f(fn3);  // Actually works

  return 0;
}
```

When I first wrote this I expected that calling `fn1()` inside `f()` would properly return a reference to the `str` in `main`. Given that `str` is allocated until after `f()` returns, this looked fine to me. But what actually happens is that trying to access the return of `fn1()` inside `f()` segfaults.

The same thing happens with `fn2()`, but what is surprising is that `fn3()` works properly.

Given that `fn3()` works and `fn1()` doesn't, is there something I'm missing about how C++ deduces the return values of lambda functions? How would that create this segfault?

For the record, here are the outputs if I run this code:

calling only `f(fn3)`:

```
in main
fn1: a
fn2: a
fn3: a
in f
str: a
```

calling only `f(fn2)`:

```
in main
fn1: a
fn2: a
fn3: a
in f
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

calling only `f(fn1)`:

```
in main
fn1: a
fn2: a
fn3: a
in f
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: The first two lambdas return by value, and therefore are incompatible with the `std::function` which expects a callable that returns by reference. I don't know why this compiles as I'd expect it to fail when trying to construct the `std::function` with an incompatible callable type.

Comment: This is your program when running it in [valgrind](https://pastebin.com/dxMTPadD).

Comment: One suggestion concerning this kind of errors: Check the address of whatever the functions or lambdas return to make sure that the result of `f1()` is identical to `str`, i.e. `assert(&str == &f1());`.

Comment: seems clang doesn't break: https://godbolt.org/z/PtJc3j

Comment: Both gcc and clang compile with this code. This also surprises me.

Comment: @oblivion - clang doesn't segfault, but returns garbage. So it is still a problem.

Comment: When you get a segfault, show the backtrace.

Comment: As a side note, the fact that `std::function<const T &()>` accepts `T()` functions, with an automatic dangling reference, is an, err, undocumented feature.

Comment: "feature" hahaha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lambda without trailing return type as in:

```
[&](){return str;};
```

Is equivalent to:

```
[&]()->auto{return str;};
```

So this lambda returns a copy of str.

Calling the `std::function` object will result in this equivalent code:

```
const string& std_function_call_operator(){
    // functor = [&]->auto{return str;};

    return functor();
    }
```

When this function is called, `str` is copied inside a temporary, the reference is bound to this temporary and then the temporary is destroyed. So you get the famous dangling reference. This is a very classical scenario.

Comment: Ugh, so easy to do. Naughty C++!

Answer (score 1):

The return type deduction of lambda is changed [N3638](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1048). and now the return type of a `lambda` uses the `auto` return type deduction rules, which strips the referenceness.
Hence, `[&]() { return str;};` returns `string`. As a result, in void `f(std::function<const std::string&()> fn)` calling `fn()` returns a dangling reference. Binding a reference to a temporary extends the lifetime of the temporary, but in this case the binding happened deep inside `std::function`'s machinery, so by the time `f()` returns, the temporary is gone already.

**lambda deduction rule**

> auto and lambda return types use slightly different rules for
>   determining the result type from an expression. auto uses the rules in
>   17.9.2.1 [temp.deduct.call], which explicitly drops top-level cv-qualification in all cases, while the lambda return type is based
>   on the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, which drops cv-qualification only
>   for non-class types. As a result:
>
> ```
> struct A { };
>
> const A f();
>
> auto a = f();               // decltype(a) is A
> auto b = []{ return f(); }; // decltype(b()) is const A This seems like an unnecessary inconsistency.
> ```
>
> John Spicer:
>
> The difference is intentional; auto is intended only to give a const
>   type if you explicitly ask for it, while the lambda return type should
>   generally be the type of the expression.
>
> Daniel Krügler:
>
> Another inconsistency: with auto, use of a `braced-init-list` can deduce
>   a specialization of `std::initializer_list;` it would be helpful if the
>   same could be done for a lambda return type.
>
> Additional note, February, 2014:
>
> EWG noted that g++ and clang differ in their treatment of this example
>   and referred it back to CWG for resolution.

Let's see what is deduced in your [code](https://godbolt.org/z/BAjlwd):

```
fn1: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >

fn2: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >

fn3: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&
```

as you can see only the last one is actually a `const&`

you can check return types of your lambdas with the following code:

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/10933809
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f(std::function<const std::string&()> fn) {
  std::cout << "in f" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "str: " << fn() << std::endl;
}
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#   include <cxxabi.h>
#endif
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

template <class T>
std::string
type_name()
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type TR;
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> own
           (
#ifndef _MSC_VER
                abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(TR).name(), nullptr,
                                           nullptr, nullptr),
#else
                nullptr,
#endif
                std::free
           );
    std::string r = own != nullptr ? own.get() : typeid(TR).name();
    if (std::is_const<TR>::value)
        r += " const";
    if (std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
        r += " volatile";
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&";
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&&";
    return r;
}
int main() {
  std::string str = "a";

  auto fn1 = [&]() { return str; };
  auto fn2 = [&]() { const std::string& str2 = str; return str2; };
  auto fn3 = [&]() -> const std::string& { return str; };

  std::cout << "in main" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "fn1: " << fn1() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "fn2: " << fn2() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "fn3: " << fn3() << std::endl;
auto f1=fn1();
  std::cout << "fn1: " << type_name<decltype(fn1())>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "fn2: " << type_name<decltype(fn2())>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "fn3: " << type_name<decltype(fn3())>() << std::endl;

  f(fn1);  // Segfaults
  f(fn2);  // Also segfaults
  f(fn3);  // Actually works

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your restriction are wrong, lambda can have several statements and even several return-statements without having to specify the return type explicitly.

Comment: @Jarod42 it is the case for c++11 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#975. I edit the answer

Comment: You can "ask" the compiler to give you the type name inside an error message:[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hDnB4m)

Comment: @Oliv I wasn't aware of that, do you have a link?

Comment: I understand why fn1 would be deduced as a plain std::string. But why this would happen with fn2? Given I'm returning a const ref, shouldn't the deduced return value be a const std::string&?

Comment: Also, why would fn1 and fn2 compile given that the type signatures are different than what the std::function expected?

Comment: @RenatoUtsch I edited the answer.  the deduction rule's been changed from c++11

Comment: @RenatoUtsch You can find the appropriate information on cpp reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable look for implicitly convertible.