# How to access attribute of spirit rule, if attribute types of rule and parser don't match?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Using boost::spirit::qi for parsing, there's the possibility to use semantic actions to call functions via phoenix. The result can then be assigned to the rule's attribute, using `boost::qi::_val`, in case the attribute type of the rule and the assigned parser match. In case the types differ, the label `qi::_val` stands for the top attribute. This is the case in the following short working example, as the parsers for the rules `add` and `mul` return `tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t>`, while the rules themself expect `vector<std::size_t>`:

```cpp
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

/* useful abbreviations */
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace ph = boost::phoenix;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ql = qi::labels;


namespace parser
{

/* these functions are called by the semantic actions */
std::vector<std::size_t> add(std::size_t a, std::size_t b)
{
    return std::vector<std::size_t>{a, b, a+b};
}

std::vector<std::size_t> mul(std::size_t a, std::size_t b)
{
    return std::vector<std::size_t>{a, b, a*b};
}

/* actual grammar */
template<typename Iterator>
class Parser : public boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<std::size_t>(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type>
{
public:
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(packed)
    {
        packed %= *(add | mul | val) >> qi::eoi;
        add = (qi::uint_ >> '+' >> qi::uint_ >> ';')[ qi::_val = ph::bind(&parser::add, ql::_1, ql::_2) ];
        mul = (qi::uint_ >> '*' >> qi::uint_ >> ';')[ qi::_val = ph::bind(&parser::mul, ql::_1, ql::_2) ];
        val %= qi::uint_ >> ';';
    }

private:
    using Rule = boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::size_t>(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type>;
    Rule packed;
    Rule add;
    Rule mul;
    Rule val;
};

} /* namespace parser */

/* MAIN PROGRAM */
int main()
{
    using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;
    parser::Parser<Iterator> parser;
    std::vector<std::size_t> result;
    
    std::string string = "1; 2*4; 5; 6; 7+9; 10;";
    Iterator it = string.begin(), end = string.end();
    qi::phrase_parse(it, end, parser, ascii::space, result);
    
    std::cout << "[ ";
    for(auto i: result) std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << "]\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[ 7, 9, 16, 10, ]
```

The not-expected-but-really-wanted output would be:

```
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 16, 10, ]
```

As you can see, the assignment `qi::_val = ph::bind(&add, ql::_1, ql::_2)` simply overwrites everything in the top rules attribute. I know I can work around this, by appending to the top rules attribute, but I'd like to keep things clean and have this done by the parser of the rule `packed`.

Is there a nice and easy way to write the result of the calls to `parser::add` and `parser::mul` to their respective rules' attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My usual suggestion here is to simply not conflate parsing and evaluation. That would make this much simpler, since you could just print all operands during evaluation.

See the **SEPARATION OF CONCERNS** section below.

### Do It Anyways

You can of course do it manually, by making the functions do what you want:

```
void add(Vec& vec, size_t a, size_t b) {
    vec.insert(vec.end(), {a, b, a+b});
}

void mul(Vec& vec, size_t a, size_t b) {
    vec.insert(vec.end(), {a, b, a*b});
}
```

And then call them as such:

```
packed %= *((add | mul | val) >> ';') >> qi::eoi;
add = (qi::uint_ >> '+' >> qi::uint_) [add_(_val, _1, _2)];
mul = (qi::uint_ >> '*' >> qi::uint_) [mul_(_val, _1, _2)];
val = qi::repeat(1) [ qi::uint_ ];
```

> Note a few minor tweaks, including the more elegant `ph::function<>` instead of `ph::bind`:
>
> ```
>     ph::function<PackedF> 
>         add_{&parser::add},
>         mul_{&parser::mul};
> ```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d8d1ecdc487b6cd)**

Prints

```
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 16, 10, ]
```

### More Simpler?

You could do all the inserts in the semantic action directly:

```
add = (qi::uint_ >> '+' >> qi::uint_) [ (
     ph::push_back(_val, _1),
     ph::push_back(_val, _2),
     ph::push_back(_val, _1 + _2)
    )
];
mul = (qi::uint_ >> '*' >> qi::uint_) [ (
     ph::push_back(_val, _1),
     ph::push_back(_val, _2),
     ph::push_back(_val, _1 * _2)
    )
];
val = qi::repeat(1) [ qi::uint_ ];
```

Arguably this would make more sense with something more dynamic:

```
_binop.add("+", std::plus<size_t>{});
_binop.add("*", std::multiplies<size_t>{});
_binop.add("-", std::minus<size_t>{});
_binop.add("/", std::divides<size_t>{});
_binop.add("^", static_cast<double(*)(double, double)>(&std::pow));

bin = (qi::uint_ >> _binop >> qi::uint_) [ (
     ph::push_back(_val, _1),
     ph::push_back(_val, _3),
     ph::push_back(_val, ph::bind(_2, _1, _3))
    ) ];
```

Here, `_binop` is a symbol table:

```
qi::symbols<char, std::function<size_t(size_t, size_t)> > _binop;
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/799b818100f50ef3)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

/* useful abbreviations */
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace ph = boost::phoenix;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ql = qi::labels;

using Vec = std::vector<size_t>;

namespace parser
{
    template <typename Iterator>
    class Parser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Vec(), ascii::space_type> {
      public:
        Parser() : Parser::base_type(packed) {
            using namespace ql;
            packed %= *((bin | val) >> ';') >> qi::eoi;

            _binop.add("+", std::plus<size_t>{});
            _binop.add("*", std::multiplies<size_t>{});
            _binop.add("-", std::minus<size_t>{});
            _binop.add("/", std::divides<size_t>{});
            _binop.add("^", static_cast<double(*)(double, double)>(&std::pow));

            bin = (qi::uint_ >> _binop >> qi::uint_) [ (
                 ph::push_back(_val, _1),
                 ph::push_back(_val, _3),
                 ph::push_back(_val, ph::bind(_2, _1, _3))
                ) ];
            val = qi::repeat(1) [ qi::uint_ ];
        }

      private:
        using Rule = qi::rule<Iterator, Vec(), ascii::space_type>;
        Rule packed, bin, val;
        qi::symbols<char, std::function<size_t(size_t, size_t)> > _binop;
    };

} /* namespace parser */

/* MAIN PROGRAM */
int main() {
    using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;
    parser::Parser<Iterator> parser;
    Vec result;

    std::string string = "1; 2*4; 5; 6; 7+9; 10;";
    Iterator it = string.begin(), end = string.end();
    qi::phrase_parse(it, end, parser, ascii::space, result);

    std::cout << "[ ";
    for (auto i : result)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << "]\n";
}
```

Prints (again):

```
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 16, 10, ]
```

### Even more simpler?

You can avoid backtracking the values by rewording the rules:

```
expr_list = expr % ';' >> qi::eol;

auto val = qi::copy(qi::uint_ [ ph::push_back(_val, _1) ]);
auto penultimate = *(ph::rbegin(_val)+1);

expr = val >> *(_binop >> val) 
    [ ph::push_back(_val, ph::bind(_1, penultimate, _2)) ];
```

This is widely more *expressive*:

```
std::string const string = "1; 2*4; 2^7-1; 4-1*2";
```

Result in: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e88fb870be9d9389)**:

```
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 2, 7, 128, 1, 127, 4, 1, 3, 2, 6, ]
```

As you can see this is getting more towards general arithmetic expression evaluation. If you wanted this, make sure you go the extra step of doing operator precedence rules. I have many answers up on this site showing some approaches.

### SEPARATION OF CONCERNS INSTEAD

So, if you didn't want to "do it anyways", I'd parse into a list of elements first:

```
namespace parser {
    using Operand = std::size_t;
    struct Binary {
        Operand lhs;
        char operator_;
        Operand rhs;
    };
    using Element = boost::variant<Operand, Binary>;
    using Elements = std::vector<Element>;
    using boost::fusion::operator<<;
} // namespace parser
```

This is mostly simpler because we don't need a single semantic action anymore, nor do we need to evaluate anything:

```
template <typename Iterator>
class Parser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Elements(), qi::space_type> {
  public:
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(packed) {
        packed = (bin | qi::uint_) % ';' >> qi::eoi;
        bin = qi::uint_ >> qi::char_("-+*/^") >> qi::uint_;
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, Elements(), qi::space_type> packed;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Binary(), qi::space_type> bin;
};
```

That's what I call *simple*. Now, using it is ***as** simple*:

```
parser::Elements elements;

std::string string = "1; 2*4; 5; 6; 7+9; 10;";
Iterator it = string.begin(), end = string.end();
qi::phrase_parse(it, end, parser, qi::space, elements);

for (auto& element : elements)
    std::cout << element << "; ";
```

This prints

```
1; (2 * 4); 5; 6; (7 + 9); 10;
```

As you can see, we know have the input parsed, we can evaluate it. In fact, we can evaluate the same elements in different ways:

```
std::vector<Operand> evaluate(Elements const& elements, bool include_literals = true) {
    struct {
        bool literals;
        std::vector<Operand> result;
        void operator()(Operand const& oper) { result.push_back(oper); }
        void operator()(Binary const& bin) { 
            if (literals) {
                operator()(bin.lhs);
                operator()(bin.rhs);
            }
            switch(bin.operator_) {
                case '+': operator()(bin.lhs + bin.rhs); break;
                case '-': operator()(bin.lhs - bin.rhs); break;
                case '*': operator()(bin.lhs * bin.rhs); break;
                case '/': operator()(bin.lhs / bin.rhs); break;
                case '^': operator()(std::pow(bin.lhs, bin.rhs)); break;
            }
        }
    } vis;

    vis.literals = include_literals;

    for (auto& el : elements)
        apply_visitor(vis, el);

    return vis.result;
}
```

> This evaluation is pretty straight-forward, but uses a technique that might be new: the [**variant visitor**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/variant.html#variant.motivation). The standard library calls `apply_visitor` [`visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Now we can choose whether to include the literal operands or not:

```
std::cout << "\nwithout literals [ ";
for (auto i : evaluate(elements, false)) std::cout << i << ", ";
std::cout << "]\n";

std::cout << "with literals [ ";
for (auto i : evaluate(elements, true)) std::cout << i << ", ";
std::cout << "]\n";
```

Prints

```
without literals [ 1, 8, 5, 6, 16, 10, ]
with literals [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6, 7, 9, 16, 10, ]
```

### OTHER BENEFITS

Another (non obvious) benefit of this approach is that it makes it easier to have some kind of operator precedence. This is getting off-topic, bit let me indulge a few tweaks and sample evaluations (without going as far as making the parser aware of precedence):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e553bf351d1049a)**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

/* useful abbreviations */
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace parser {
    using Operand = std::size_t;
    struct Binary;
    using Element = boost::variant<Operand, boost::recursive_wrapper<Binary> >;

    struct Binary {
        Element lhs;
        char operator_;
        Element rhs;
    };

    using Elements = std::vector<Element>;
    using boost::fusion::operator<<;
} // namespace parser
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(parser::Binary, lhs, operator_, rhs)

namespace parser {
    /* actual grammar */
    template <typename Iterator>
    class Parser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Elements(), qi::space_type> {
      public:
        Parser() : Parser::base_type(packed) {
            packed = elem % ';' >> qi::eoi;
            elem   = bin | qi::uint_;
            bin    = '(' >> elem >> qi::char_("-+*/^") >> elem >> ')';

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((packed)(elem)(bin))
        }

      private:
        qi::rule<Iterator, Elements(), qi::space_type> packed;
        qi::rule<Iterator, Element(), qi::space_type> elem;
        qi::rule<Iterator, Binary(), qi::space_type> bin;
    };

    Elements parse(std::string const& input) {
        using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;
        static const parser::Parser<Iterator> parser;
        Elements elements;
        qi::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser, qi::space, elements);
        // TODO error handling please
        return elements;
    }

    std::vector<Operand> evaluate(Elements const& elements) {
        struct {
            Operand operator()(Element const& el) { return boost::apply_visitor(*this, el); }
            Operand operator()(Operand const& oper) { return oper; }
            Operand operator()(Binary const& bin) { 
                auto lhs = operator()(bin.lhs);
                auto rhs = operator()(bin.rhs);
                switch(bin.operator_) {
                    case '+': return operator()(lhs + rhs);
                    case '-': return operator()(lhs - rhs);
                    case '*': return operator()(lhs * rhs);
                    case '/': return operator()(lhs / rhs);
                    case '^': return operator()(std::pow(lhs, rhs));
                }
                throw std::invalid_argument("operator not implemented");
            }
        } vis;

        std::vector<Operand> result;
        for (auto& el : elements) {
            result.push_back(apply_visitor(vis, el));
        }

        return result;
    }

} /* namespace parser */

/* MAIN PROGRAM */
int main() {
    auto const elements = parser::parse("1; ((2*4)+7); (2*(4+7)); ((7-4)^4);");

    for (auto& element : elements)
        std::cout << element << "; ";

    std::cout << "\nevaluated ";
    for (auto i : evaluate(elements))
        std::cout << i << ", ";
}
```

Prints

```
1; ((2 * 4) + 7); (2 * (4 + 7)); ((7 - 4) ^ 4);
evaluated 1, 15, 22, 81,
```

Comment: Wow, that's a long answer, and there's a lot of good stuff in there, thank you @sehe. But my real question hast not been answered. I admit, I'm having troubles formulating it correctly. The question itself is much more general and not tied to a specific use case: If I have a rule and a parser with differing types and a function, that converts the parser result into something the rule can save. Is there a way to modify the rule's attribute without touching the top attribute?

Comment: @WolfgangLorenz Maybe you should come up with a different, compelling example, because I did address precisely that question /with/ the example you provided. The solution takes up the "Do It Anyways" (3 paras with [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d8d1ecdc487b6cd)). I suggest you post it as a new question (perhaps linking this one) to avoid muddying the question.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you're aware of the general meaning of `operator %=` for rule initialization [see highlight](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html#boost-common-heading-doc-spacer:~:text=Auto%2Drule%20definition.%20The%20attribute%20of%20p,may%20not%20change%20the%20attribute's%20type)

Comment: Trying to read your question completely unrelated to the example (which is NOT about attribute conversion but about attribute manipulation): For conversion see [attr_cast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/attr_cast.html) and [transform_attribute](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/transform.html#spirit.advanced.customize.transform.module_headers) (for which I have [samples on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+qi+transform_attribute) too)

Comment: The [same is a recurring topic for Spirit X3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819120/spirit-x3-how-to-get-attribute-type-to-match-rule-type/56824271#56824271)

Comment: I've done some experiments now ([silly word repetition](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dee02bfb6837297) and [nested number sequences](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae64e9e205ade33e) - for some reason, they fail to run on coliru). Both work as indendet, but not as expected. I think my main problem is, that I don't understand what qi::_val actually points to. If it were the attribute of the top rule, the first example would have failed to compile and the second one would have delivered other results.

Comment: So I guess, your post DOES answer my question, and I just don't understant the most important part.

Comment: Also: I wasn't aware, that `operator =` behaves like `operator %=`, if no semantic actions are attached. Has this always been that case?

And I would think of it more as "attribute generation", where the attributes of the parser might not have anything to do with, what the assigned rule expects. But I'm not going to fight about terms, because I know I would lose. ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225692/discussion-between-sehe-and-wolfgang-lorenz).