# How to check the exact type info (with cv-ref-pointer traits) in C++?

Tags: c++, standards, type-traits, abi, typeid

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << typeid(int).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(int&).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(int&&).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(const int).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(const int&).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(const int&&).name() << endl;
}
```

I think the output should be:

```
int
int&
int&&
const int
const int&
const int&&
```

However, the real output is:

```
int
int
int
int
int
int
```

Both of clang & vc++ do the same way.

**Is there a reliable way to check the exact type name (with cv-ref-pointer traits) in C++?**

Comment: Not in a portable way.

Comment: Any implemetation-defined way is also acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to print a variable's type in standard C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c)

Answer (score 2):

Note that when you pass a reference type to [typeid operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), the result `std::type_info` object represents the referenced type. And cv-qualifiers will be ignored.

> 1) Refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type `type`. If `type` is a reference type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the referenced type
>
> In all cases, cv-qualifiers are ignored by typeid (that is, `typeid(const T) == typeid(T)`)

And note that what [`std::type_info::name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) returns is implementation-defined.

You can apply the trick from *[Effective Modern C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491903996)* (Scott Meyers) *Item 4: Know how to view deduced types*, to get the type name at compile-time. e.g.

```
template <typename>
struct TD;
```

then use it as

```
TD<int> td;
```

you'll get some message mentioning the type name, like

> ```
> error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<int>'
> ```

[LIVE (clang)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8xfeIYeK4Rn0YqMu)

Comment: You can also define the template and print its typeid name.