# clang: error: assigning to 'int (*)[y][z]' from incompatible type 'int (*)[y][z]'

Tags: c++, gcc, types, clang

Why does clang (9.0.0) fail to compile this code? GCC (9.2.0) has no problems with it.

Using `typedef int arr[y][z]; arr *a;` or `auto a = ...` works fine, but using the type inline gives the strange error message of `error: assigning to 'int (*)[y][z]' from incompatible type 'int (*)[y][z]'`. These types look pretty compatible to me. Is it possible that two different types have the same syntax?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x, y, z;

    std::cin >> x >> y >> z;

    int (*a)[y][z];
    a = (int(*)[y][z]) new int[x * y * z];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < z; k++) {
                std::cin >> a[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < z; k++) {
                std::cout << a[i][j][k];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] a;

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ clang++ code.cpp -o code
code.cpp:9:6: error: assigning to 'int (*)[y][z]' from incompatible type 'int (*)[y][z]'
        a = (int(*)[y][z]) new int[x * y * z];
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
$ g++ code.cpp -o code
$
```

Comment: Variable length arrays are not part of c++. Use `std::vector`. This is most probably a compiler bug in handling variable length arrays in C++.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: seems reasonable that an illegal type is considered incompatible with another illegal type (kind of like how NaN != NaN)

Comment: @KamilCuk what's a simple way to create a fast variable length multi-dimensional array in C++? `int (*a)[y][z] = (int(*)[y][z]) new int[x * y * z];` is a one-liner that automatically initializes a multi-dimensional array and keeps it in a contiguous block of memory. Is there a better C++ way of doing it?

Comment: If you `auto a = (int(*)[y][z]) new int[x * y * z];` and then print the type using the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c (`std::cout << type_name<decltype(a)>() << '\n';`), it compiles under clang and prints the type as expected, i.e. `int (*)[y][z]`.

(Apologies for posting this as an answer earlier. Deleted. My intent was to highlight that this code can be made to compile and work with the expected types under clang, and thus perhaps highlight a compiler oddity or spark inspiration in someone else.)

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37828

Comment: `what's a simple` that would be something along: `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> a(x, std::vector<std::vector<int>>(y, std::vector<int>(z)));` Variable length arrays are not part of C++. You will theoretically earn speed because it's in a "continuous block of memory", but unless you write specifically speed optimized software (that usually uses architecture details anyway), it's not worth it. It's not safe. It's easy to make an error (What if `x` is negative? What if `x` is zero?) It's not reliable. It obfuscates easy things. Is not readable. Just use `vector`.