# Why does `std::add_pointer`, adds a previously removed `const`?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

Apologies if the title is a bit misleading.. Here's the situation.

Consider the following example:

```
template<typename T>
static std::string demangle_typename()
{
    int status = 0;
    return abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(),nullptr,nullptr,&status);
}

void foo()
{  
    typedef const int* Type;
    std::cout<< demangle_typename<Type>() <<std::endl;   // type is: int const *  <ok>
}
```

The type is `int const *`

Now, when I remove the `const *` part using `std::remove_pointer` and the I use `std::add_pointer` to add the pointer back without the `const`, the constness reappears. Why?

```
void foo()
{  
    typedef const int* Type;
    std::cout<< demangle_typename<Type>() <<std::endl;   // type is: int const *  <ok>

    typedef typename std::remove_pointer<Type>::type rp_Type;   // int
    typedef typename std::add_pointer<rp_Type>::type p_Type;    // int const *  <???>

    std::cout<< demangle_typename<p_Type>() <<std::endl;   // type is: int const *  <???>
}
```

To get the pointer without the `const` I need to use `std::remove_const`. But why is this needed, since `std::remove_pointer` has already removed the `const`?

```
void foo()
{  
    typedef const int* Type;
    std::cout<< demangle_typename<Type>() <<std::endl;   // type is: int const *  <ok>

    typedef typename std::remove_pointer<Type>::type rp_Type;  // int
    typedef typename std::remove_const<rp_Type>::type rc_Type; // int
    typedef typename std::add_pointer<rc_Type>::type p_Type;   // int*

    std::cout<< demangle_typename<p_Type>() <<std::endl;   // type is: int*  <ok>
}
```

Online code example: https://rextester.com/YYE94945

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: It's what I got from the online compiler... I'll switch to boost because according to one of the answers, `typeid` discard top-level cv qualifiers.

Comment: See the link in my answer for better approaches for examining type. This problem is explicitly discussed there too. You don't need Boost.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos Just curious, what are planning to use boost for? There's something in it that prints type names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeid` discards top-level cv-qualifiers on types. It doesn't see any difference between `int` and `const int`.

`std::remove_pointer_t<const int *>` is `const int` rather than `int`, but `const` doesn't get printed because of that.

Comment: How come it doesn't show up then and it prints out just `int`? Also, according to the online documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer), `std::remove_pointer` should remove both the constness and the pointer. It says: `template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* const>          {typedef T type;};`

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos Because `typeid` ignores any top-level cv-qualifiers on the type. It doesn't see any difference between `int` and `const int`. (I'll clarify the answer.) *"should remove both the constness and the pointer"* In this snippet the `const` is to the right of `*` ("const pointer to T"). So the pointer itself is `const`, and this constness is removed along with `*`. In the question you have `const` to the left of `*` ("non-const pointer to const int"), so the pointer itself is not `const`.

Comment: Oh I see! The specialization of `std::remove_pointer` refers to a `int * const`, not  a `const int *`. I got confused with the type not showing up. I should have used boost to avoid this confusion! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `demangle_typename` is not fit for purpose here: it won't show you top-level `const`, so your results are not correct observations. ([It can be fixed, though!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/560648))

`rp_Type` is not `int` but `const int`.

Removing a pointer layer does not remove pointee constness.

So the `const` is not "added"; it was never actually removed. You just don't observe it, with your solution, when it's top-level.

Comment: Yep! Rubish usage of `typeid` from my part.