# Can a member function returns a modifiable lvalue reference to an rvalue object?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, lvalue

I have a bit confusion about this code:

```
struct A
{
    A& bar()&&;
};

A& A::bar()&&
{
    std::cout << "A::bar()&&\n";
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    A{}.bar();// called by an rvalue
}
```

So what I understand is that `bar` can be called only by a modifiable-rvalue. Until this it is OK. But how can `bar` return a non-constant lvalue reference to that rvalue?

- How `bar()` binds and returns a modifiable lvalue reference to that rvalue object?

Comment: It just can. C++ lets you shoot yourself in the foot if you want to. You can also *reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x1234)++ if you insist.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if we can consider this a defect with the language.  It would be cool if we could have `*this` resolves to `T&&` if the function is `&&` qualified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `this` pointer for a class `C` can be either `C*` or `const C*` - not `C& *` or `C&& *` (those aren't actual types; you can't declare a `C& * ptr`). So, even when your method runs for an rvalue instance of class `A`, you [get one of those two](https://godbolt.org/z/3h8wR-) (GodBolt). And when you apply the `*` operator, you [get an lvalue](https://godbolt.org/z/3h8wR-), not an rvalue.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Maestro: We should both thank [Howard Hinnant and @康桓瑋 for developing the neat `type_name<T>()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81870/1593077). It should really get more attention IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with [[expr.unary.op]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary.op#1)

> The unary `*` operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and **the result is an lvalue** referring to the object or function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression is “pointer to `T`”, the type of the result is “`T`”. [ Note: Indirection through a pointer to an incomplete type (other than cv void) is valid. The lvalue thus obtained can be used in limited ways (to initialize a reference, for example); this lvalue must not be converted to a prvalue, see [conv.lval]. — end note ]

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So when you dereference `this` yo get an lvalue.  It doesn't matter if this is pointing to a temporary object or not, you will always get an lvalue.  Since `*this` is an lvalue, you are legally allowed to return an lvalue reference, the program in *syntactically* correct.  *Semantically* it is not, but that is a lot harder to test for and is often not something that is diagnosed as it requires quite a bit of static analysis.

---

It would be cool if the language could be updated where `*` only yields an lvalue when applied to `this` in a non-rvalue qualified function.

Comment: Really amazing! So this because "dereference operator" yields an lvalue thus it can be bound to a non-const lvalue reference? Another thing is that an rvalue-refrence itself is an lvalue although it refrs to an rvalue. Is this true? Thank you!

Comment: @Maestro Yep to question 1. Yes, that is true, for question 2.  **All** references are lvalues.  Also anything with a name is an lvalue, except for `this`

Comment: Ah ok! I missed the last one "about this". thank you.