# Why can't we assign address of array to pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, declaration, implicit-conversion

```
int q[10]={0};
cout << q << endl;
cout << &q << endl;
cout << &q[0] << endl;
```

output is

```
0x7fffd4d2f860 
0x7fffd4d2f860 
0x7fffd4d2f860
```

Now when i do this->

```
int *r=q;    // allowed
int *r=&q[0] // allowed
int *r=&q    // not allowed
```

Why is the third assignment not allowed when it is essentially the same thing?

Comment: `&q` would be `int **`

Comment: Then why does cout print same things in all of the three cases?

Comment: @jamesgem Because there is an `operator<<(void*)` defined for `std::ostream`, and `void*` can accept ANY type of pointer (well, almost any). All three of your `<<` calls resolve to the same memory address, which is why they all print the same number.

Comment: @jamesgem You seem to be confusing **type** and **value**.  `cout` prints the value.  `cout` will not tell you if an expression is a valid type for assignment.

Comment: My compiler spits out the following error:`error: cannot convert 'int (*)[10]' to 'int*' in initialization` From that it's pretty easy to see that the type is wrong.Good compiler messages are golden.

Comment: Just because the printed values are the same doesn't mean the types of the expressions are the same.

Comment: @Timo Not only is `&q` not `int**`, but also it does not decay to it. Pointers to arrays do not decay.

Comment: @Timo [`&q` does not decay into an `int**`](https://ideone.com/523n42)

Comment: To answer the question in the title literally, you **can** assign the address of an array to a pointer, but the pointer has to have the right type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have an array declared like

```
T a[N];
```

where `T` is some type specifier then a pointer to the array will be declared like

```
T ( *p )[N] = &a;
```

A general rule is the following. If you have a multidimensional array (including one-dimensional arrays) like for example

```
T a[N1][N2][N3];
```

then this declaration you may rewrite like

```
T ( a[N1] )[N2][N3];
```

To get a pointer to the first element of the array just substitute the content in the parentheses the following way

```
T ( *p )[N2][N3] = a;
```

If you want to get a pointer to the whole array then rewrite the declaration of the array like

```
T ( a )[N1][N2][N3];
```

and make the substitution

```
T ( *p )[N1][N2][N3] = &a;
```

Compare this with a declaration of a scalar object and a pointer to it.

For example

```
T obj;
```

You may rewrite the declaration like

```
T ( obj );
```

Now to get a pointer to the object you can write

```
T ( *p ) = &obj;
```

Of course in this case the parentheses are redundant and the above declaration is equivalent to

```
T *p = &obj;
```

As for this code snippet

```
int q[10]={0};
cout << q << endl;
cout << &q << endl;
cout << &q[0] << endl;
```

and its output

```
0x7fffd4d2f860 
0x7fffd4d2f860 
0x7fffd4d2f860
```

then array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So in fact the two expression `q` and `&q[0]` in these statements

```
cout << q << endl;
cout << &q[0] << endl;
```

are equivalent. On the other hand, the address of the array itself is the address of the memory extent that the array occupies. And in the beginning of the extent there is the first element of the array. So the three expressions give the same result: the address of the extent of memory occupied by the array.

Comment: This would make a nice FAQ answer imo.

Comment: Change the cout's to something like `cout << q << " " << typeid(q).name() << endl;`, that'll provide some insight (I hope).  Need a `#include <typeinfo>` too.

Comment: @Eljay `typeid(something).name()` does not provide human-understandable output in most cases. I implemented your suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75272572/8659747).

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the third assignment not allowed when it is essentially the same thing?

Because The C++ language has a feature called "type safety". There is a type system that helps you keep the logic of your program sound.

One particular rule is that arbitrary pointer types can not be used to initialise pointers of other, incompatible types. In this case, you have a pointer to type int (.i.e. `int*`) that you try to initalise with an expression of type pointer to type array of 10 int (i.e. `int(*)[10]`). One type is not implicitly convertible to the other, hence the program is ill-formed.

> Then why does cout print same things in all of the three cases?

Because all of the pointers have the same value. The first byte of the first element of the array is the same byte as the first byte of the entire array.

It just so happens that the stream insertion operator handles all pointer types<sup>1</sup> exactly the same, so pointers with same value but different type produce the same output.

<sup>1</sup> Pointers to character types are an exception. They are treated entirely differently.

---

> Why can't we assign address of array to pointer?

Actually, we can assign address of an array to a pointer. We just cannot assign address of a array (or any other object for that matter) to a *pointer of wrong type*. We need a pointer to an array in this case:

```
int (*r)[10] = &q;
```

Comment: yup, my bad, I just realized that

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do the third assignment because `&q`'s type is an `int (*)[10]`, which is incompatible with the type of `int* r`.

The output of `cout << &q` does not reveal the type of `&q`. See [this](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/) documentation link.

Comment: Then why does cout print same things in all of the three cases?

Comment: Regarding the edit: `int*[10]` is different from `int (*)[10]`. One is an array of pointers, and the other is a pointer to an array.

Comment: Do you have a link to some documentation regarding this notation?

Comment: [there you go](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array)

Comment: Learned something today!

Answer (score 1):

`q` is a fixed-length array. Specifying `q` by itself in an expression [*decays*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) into a pointer to the 1st element of `q`.  Thus, `q` *decays* to the same pointer value that `&q[0]` returns.  `&q`, on the other hand, returns the memory address of the `q` variable itself, and for an array, its 1st element occupies that same memory address.

There is an `operator<<(void*)` defined for `std::ostream`, and `void*` can accept (almost) ANY type of pointer.  Since all three of your `cout` calls resolve to the same memory address, and there is an `operator<<` that accepts all three types of pointers, that is why all three calls print the same number.

As for your assignments:

- `q` is an `int[10]`, which *decays* into an `int*`, which is why `int *r=q;` works.
- `&q[0]` dereferences `q` to access its 1st element, which is an `int`, and then takes the address of that element, producing an `int*`, which is why `int *r=&q[0];` works.
- since `q` is an `int[10]`, `&q` is an `int(*)[10]`, which DOES NOT *decay* into an `int*`, which is why `int *r=&q;` does not work.  You would have to declare `r` using the correct type:

  `int (*r)[10] = &q;`

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates the differences between `arr`, `&arr` and `&arr[0]` where `arr` is an array of integers.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

// Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c/56766138#56766138
// Type finding code start
template <typename T>
constexpr auto type_name()
{
    std::string_view name, prefix, suffix;
#ifdef __clang__
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    prefix = "auto type_name() [T = ";
    suffix = "]";
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    prefix = "constexpr auto type_name() [with T = ";
    suffix = "]";
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    name = __FUNCSIG__;
    prefix = "auto __cdecl type_name<";
    suffix = ">(void)";
#endif
    name.remove_prefix(prefix.size());
    name.remove_suffix(suffix.size());
    return name;
}
// Type finding code end

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::cout << "Value: " << arr << "\tType: " << type_name<decltype(arr)>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value: " << &arr << "\tType: " << type_name<decltype(&arr)>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value: " << &arr[0] << "\tType: " << type_name<decltype(&arr[0])>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[See it in action.](https://www.onlinegdb.com/nBsHu9O8x)

**Sample Output:**

```
Value: 0x7ffcdadd22d0   Type: int [5]
Value: 0x7ffcdadd22d0   Type: int (*)[5]
Value: 0x7ffcdadd22d0   Type: int*
```

While all three are associated with the same memory location, they are of different types.

Reference: [Is it possible to print a variable's type in standard C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c/56766138#56766138)

Comment: There is also the older Boost [demangle](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html), or the newer Boost [typename](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/type_name.html).