# How can I access the `typeid` of a captured this pointer in a lambda?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, lambda, capture

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Bobo
{public:
    int member;
    void function()
    {
        auto lambda = [this]() { std::cout << member << '\n'; };
        auto lambda2 = [this]() { std::cout << typeid(*this).name() << '\n'; };
        lambda();
        lambda2();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bobo bobo;
    bobo.function();
}
```

The line std::cout << typeid(*this).name(); in lambda2() understandably prints out:

```
class <lambda_49422032c40f80b55ca1d0ebc98f567f>
```

However how can I access the 'this' pointer that's been captured so the typeid operator can return type class Bobo?

Edit: The result I get is from compiling this code in Visual Studio Community 2019.

Comment: That's not at all "understandable" to me. Surely that's a bug. All uses of `this` should refer to the capture, not the compiler-generated lambda class, which to the user doesn't exist. I can't replicate with `g++` 9 (no options). It prints `4Bobo`, just like @songyuanyao's tests.

Comment: Can't reproduce with [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RsnfzLQdaJi0SG3Q) and [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/htcERsFq0TAtLJty). What's your compiler?

Comment: @songyuanyao I compiled with Visual Studio Community 2019 on Windows. I checked again, that's the result I get. I got the behavior I wanted by creating a local temporary variable and capturing that. Still, this isn't supposed to happen?

Comment: Nope, it's wrong. Please file a bug against VS :-)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be VS's bug; when determining the type of `this` pointer in [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> For the purpose of [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup), determining the type and value of the
>   [this pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) and for accessing non-static class members, the body of
>   the closure type's function call operator is considered in the context
>   of the lambda-expression.
>
> ```
> struct X {
>     int x, y;
>     int operator()(int);
>     void f()
>     {
>         // the context of the following lambda is the member function X::f
>         [=]()->int
>         {
>             return operator()(this->x + y); // X::operator()(this->x + (*this).y)
>                                             // this has type X*
>         };
>     }
> };
> ```

So the type of `this` should be `Bobo*` in the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

As @songyuanyao suggests, your could should work and produce the appropriate typeid, so it's probably a bug. But - here's a workaround for you:

```
#include <iostream>

class Bobo
{public:
    int member;
    void function() {
        auto lambda = [this]() { std::cout << member << '\n'; };
        auto lambda2 = [my_bobo = this]() { 
            std::cout << typeid(std::decay_t<decltype(*my_bobo)>).name() << '\n'; 
        };
        lambda();
        lambda2();
    }
};

int main() {
    Bobo bobo;
    bobo.function();
}
```

Note that you can replaced `typeid(...).name()` with the proper type name, obtained (at compile-time!) as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56766138/1593077):

```
std::cout << type_name<std::decay_t<decltype(*my_bobo)>>() << '\n';
```