# Why does ranged for loop converts value to ref implicitly?

Tags: c++

I'm very confused why `range-for` uses a ref in my example?

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const unordered_map<char, string> d2c_map= { {'1', "abc"} };
    const string digits{"1"};
    vector<string> R;
        
    for(const auto c : d2c_map.at(digits[0])) {
        R.push_back(c); // <-------------------------???
    } 
    return 0;       
}
```

Error indicates that the type of c is `const char&`:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::push_back(const char&)'
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jY84sr)

Comment: `R.emplace_back(1, c); `

Comment: There are some other issues with this code as well. First, the character `'1'` has an integer value which is not `1`. You'll need to fix that; perhaps you want to map `{'1', "abc"}` or perhaps you want to say `d2c_map.at(digits[0] - '0')`. Second, your range-based for loop copies every element of the map as you iterate over it, but you don't need the copy. Instead of `for (const auto c : ...)`, write `for (const auto& c : ...)`

Comment: @Justin thank you for pointing out the error. However the question is still there "why is 'c' a const char &??? that's my question.

Comment: `auto` doesn't deduce to a reference type, so `const auto c` will not deduce to `const char &c` in your example, but to `const char c`. The `for` loop will use `const auto c = *iterator;` where `iterator` is a `std::string::iterator`, which returns `char&` when dereferenced, but that will not make `c` deduce to `char&` but to just `char`. There are only two `push_back()`'s available in your example: `R.push_back(const string&)` and `R.push_back(string&&)`, neither of which can be called with a single `char` as input, hence the error. Where the extra `&` comes from, who knows, compiler detail.

Comment: As you are obviously interested about the internals: Have you actually checked the type of `c`, e.g using type traits and static asserts? I believe that the compiler just outputs a "wrong" error message because he tries to pass `c` as const lvalue reference first (or last). It does not really matter as oerload resolution failed and the printed message is thus ambigiuos.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann as far as I know type_traits are used for querying template arguments. However, after following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/4611344 the type of c is indeed `const char`.

Comment: @A_P How you can do this with type traits: `std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(c), const char>` (or use static_assert), then check for the types you suspect.

Answer (score 5):

> How to push each character of a string into a vector of strings?

This line is trying to add a `char` to a `vector<string>`:

```
R.push_back(c);
```

If you want to add a string constructed from the `char`, you can do:

```
R.push_back({c});
```

Comment: or change to vector<char>