# Can a function return type data?

Tags: c++, templates, types

For example i have a function like

```
template<typename T>
void DoStuffWithType()
{
//stuff based on type
}
```

and i have a function

```
"type data thing" GetTypeData()
{
  return ("type data thing")TypeA;
}
```

so calling functions

```
DoStuffWithType<TypeA>();
```

and

```
DoStuffWithType<GetTypeData()>();
```

does the same thing.

Comment: probably check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c)

Answer (score 0):

No, C++ functions cannot return data types. The closest the language has to something like this is template metaprogramming, in which we use tools like template specialization to select one of many types. For example, here's how you could select a type based on a numeric value:

```
template <int N> ChooseIfNotZero {
     using type = double;
};
template <> ChooseIfNotZero<0> {
     using type = int;
};
```

Here, the type `ChooseIfNotZero<137>::type` is `double`, while `ChooseIfNotZero<0>::type` is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

No, *types* and *values* are completely separate.

You can, however, get a type based on an expression with `decltype`:

```
TypeA GetTypeData();

DoStuffWithType<decltype(GetTypeData())>();
```

Comment: I tried it but decltype(typeid(TypeA)) is not the same as TypeA

Comment: That's because `typeid()` returns a `std::type_info` object, not a `TypeA`. Though I never even suggested that so why bring it up? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to make a required component system for the ecs i'm making

Comment: @Ciubix8513 what's ECS? What are the requirements? Looks like this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a function `GetTypeData()`. C++ is a statically typed language, so the compiler will know the types any way.

You can of course use SFINAE and have different overloads for `DoStuffWithType`.

For example:

```
template <typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void DoStuffWithType(T x)
{
 //stuff based on type
}

template <typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void DoStuffWithType(T x)
{
 //stuff based on type
}
```

You can make those enable ifs a lot more complex than this, but otherwise you use regular overloads - which are simpler and preferred.

With C++ 17, you've got `if constexpr`. So you can do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void DoStuffWithType(T x)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value)
    {
     //stuff based on type
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
    {
     //stuff based on type
    }
}
```

Comment: As you place argument to `DoStuffWithType`, regular overload is even simpler than SFINAE.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, of course. Regular overload is simpler and preferred - but this is just a demo. You can make those enable ifs more complex.