# A recursive_invoke_result_t template structure

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to implement a recursive version [`std::invoke_result_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) with C++20 concept so that the type of nested invoke result can be retrieved.

**The use case of `recursive_invoke_result_t`**

```
auto f1 = [](int x) { return static_cast<double>(x); };
std::cout << typeid(recursive_invoke_result_t<decltype(f1), int>).name() << std::endl;                  //  expected output "double"

std::cout << typeid(recursive_invoke_result_t<decltype(f1), std::vector<int>>).name() << std::endl;     //  expected output is something like "std::vector<double>"

std::cout << typeid(recursive_invoke_result_t<decltype(f1), std::vector<std::vector<int>>>).name() << std::endl;     //  expected output is something like "std::vector<std::vector<double>>"

auto f2 = [](int x) { return std::to_string(x); };
std::cout << typeid(recursive_invoke_result_t<decltype(f2), std::vector<int>>).name() << std::endl;         //  expected output is something like "std::vector<string>"

auto f3 = [](std::string x) { return std::atoi(x.c_str()); };
std::cout << typeid(recursive_invoke_result_t<decltype(f3), std::vector<std::string>>).name() << std::endl;         //  expected output is something like "std::vector<int>"
```

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation is as below.

```
//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
template<typename F, typename T>
requires (std::invocable<F, T>)
struct recursive_invoke_result_t_detail
{
    using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>;
};

template <typename F, template <typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>) && (!std::invocable<F, Container<Ts...>>)
struct recursive_invoke_result_t_detail<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<typename recursive_invoke_result_t_detail<F, std::iter_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result_t_detail<F, T>::type;
```

In the above experimental implementation, the test case `recursive_invoke_result_t<decltype(f1), int>` seems to be working fine. When it comes to the second test case `recursive_invoke_result_t<decltype(f1), std::vector<int>>`, the compile errors `'recursive_invoke_result_t_detail': the associated constraints are not satisfied`, `'recursive_invoke_result_t' : Failed to specialize alias template` and `unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation` occurred. Is there any way to solve this? Please give me some hints or examples.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
template<typename F, typename T> requires std::invocable<F, T>
struct recursive_invoke_result_t_detail
{
    using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>;
};
```

is the *primary* template for `recursive_invoke_result_t_detail`. The `requires std::invocable<F, T>` then means that `recursive_invoke_result_t_detail<F, T>` is only valid if `std::invocable<F, T>`. Period. No specialization can relax this requirement; it is a property of the template itself. The `requires` constraint on the specialization is just an added constraint: the template can only be instantiated with `<F, T>` if `std::invocable<F, T>`, and that partial specialization only applies if, further, `T = Container<Ts...>` for some `Ts...` and the other constraint you gave is satisfied (which is actually impossible!)

Leave the primary template unconstrained (and also name and alias it according to convention)

```
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };
template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;
```

Give a partial specialization for the base case

```
template<typename T, std::invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };
```

and then your other partial specialization

```
template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::invocable<F, Container<Ts...>> && // don't conflict with base case
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>> && // no idea why you asked for the contained type to be range, fixed it
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result_t<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>; }) // SFINAE-compatibility
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>> {
    using type = Container<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>>; // not iter_value_t, the container isn't an iterator!
};
```

Yum.

```
// typeid(...).name() doesn't produce anything readable for me on Godbolt
template<typename T>
std::ostream &print_type(std::ostream &out) {
    // stealing https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989
    // works only for GCC
    std::string_view name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    name.remove_prefix(50);
    name.remove_suffix(42);
    return out << name;
};
template<typename T>
constexpr void assert_no_type() { }
template<typename T> requires requires { typename T::type; }
void assert_no_type() = delete;

int main() {
    using F = decltype([](int x) -> double { return x; });
    std::cout << "double(int), int: " << print_type<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, int>> << "\n";
    std::cout << "double(int), std::vector<int>: " << print_type<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, std::vector<int>>> << "\n";
    assert_no_type<recursive_invoke_result<F, std::vector<std::ostream>>>();
    std::cout << "double(int), std::vector<std::vector<int>>: " << print_type<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, std::vector<std::vector<int>>>> << "\n";
    std::cout << "double(int), std::vector<std::set<int>>: " << print_type<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, std::vector<std::set<int>>>> << "\n";
    using G = decltype([](std::vector<int> const &v) -> std::vector<double> { return {}; });
    assert_no_type<recursive_invoke_result<G, std::set<std::set<int>>>>();
    std::cout << "std::vector<double>(std::vector<int>): " << print_type<recursive_invoke_result_t<G, std::set<std::vector<int>>>> << "\n";
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAFYAzKS3oAMnlqYAcsYBGmYiG5WADqgWE6rR6hibmvv6BdPaOLkbunt6KypiqQQwEzMQEIcamlskqanQZWQQxzm4eXlYKmdm5YQV1ZRVxCTUAlIqoBsTIHADkUhYOyIZYANTiFjpotAM%2BBAoz2OIADACCI2MTmNOzxCLAmCsWa1s7C3sHOgQAnj6YAPoER4RnF9tbBJhGPsJfjM7o8tMwjJhSJMHk9aODMKsNps6sQDKpJsRUn0AgA3F4OHGoADWL0xCgMrAI0wA7NIaQARGayH5/AHMIGzGFgiGTABiUK5cJ5ABVEVsDAFRBiscRcfjaISSc8yRSCK8DvTpchsXg8c8CcTSadVcD%2BZNRecQCAuUykUjfv9AQjOaChfthVC6ugrQaWK52MCLdg%2BWLkW80VTMdrZbr5YqjeTKaaoUGaXSJQ5gNDQRrJl6fQrDcrjZTXsnzYiLHTxNTGVW7SzHeznSDYfC%2BQLWU7gYL4QA6AerbNtnl6ejMBweAWu/sD82fJGYgCOBjwZMmECRk23kzAYHzIF9zH9LbNY8yk%2BIgYUA77leDUgAbE%2BtzuD0dRKcCz4DGqPydgXPCdHCvWZhRvQdziHF9JGfLYd2lFc11ONNh25fYox1PUDSVFVSwIct32OL8QH/F4cTYAwXgI2YgMva9b3vStq1rTokRRCMtSwuMizwmidDPOgLxAhjILWc401fbcMylLlczokTDhlOV9ULXCSzVfizSIz8FCtMjngowxqMAoTgI8US7yg6zxPE5ltlrW1LkuSRRmuAwpmBdQUUwcFQyucYPP2YElBor4ApuEK3kzQy8EwAB3fzXN2ILbjxVQSH8xs2Q5Vt0IrKCtgPfw3l8oxplgnxiAcTTQQgYqfPBCrH16AhOkk%2BCdwAei6vNfjYTNJgQAgCB8PSepaZAiVQPFiCoVhUHivs0CMLrmC6yR1k4al1gATgADl2qTJh6yZ4pIIkFEmOhWHuSYaGISYAHEdB0Y6DxRGKcTi%2BLJjdXNnmeAAFAAlbBhWFABNZ5eQAVScHRhQASQAeScQGnM2BC3T7TEjBml4qswKg8AADwgMx1jY%2BtOu3HG8YJ55ySoEnye4SRqfshDMQIPpaGu39bmBP74Uxms63sh0cpbXsRVDeY6kwUmqsmQk8HQSZmAUJRsmeWhUFeOr2prFjGWy7sXRHd0h2XVd11t5CrpNtD/uFK0bSrBkkTVjWtZ1tV9cNp4IGNixNSwdgOXspEasmIxgJDjqsZ3GSs15XMsHGLlNzMWQzHpCBY9J9qAFoh3QXoT1Qnm%2BcmUmmQZTn3oIb0UFaoXZgqyQK4ME9C/obpJhqkAu47nRJiqmqg5bTCY2wtSE1VMtZjNGr7zHrvxDMHRaCkSRMYQg80EF4Fhb3nu%2B5qweD3SohQJ0NfLVH0/O8n%2Bhp%2BBWeVJwxf8MIlurS30yrMR%2BtloKzDPpIfe29d5QIPjuP2HgA4Gw9joL%2BsZVLxmLImLSnoAEgCAffBqpU/I2VWCHeB24j7txfuPc%2Bld2D9zang1uhCoqsNSHfLy9B7wjz3hvN%2BtUnif2Uhgn%2B2Cl64L6hwjKRD8FsJATwshNkN57y3jvNRNNk5UPwcfKktCu4X0YVfFhgDOHAJ0B9TA/FQGrD4VAgR1V36oPQfPLBfFl4CVMQQ8xcjW6hW4WFJiEkDFqJgZormKdJRZiehnVIlI6pbzzgXG%2BvjAlDgVvo2COJS5DlSbI4ERjnQPlpNKXmxB%2BYm3Fg3cWTdaaa21kgvWKDQQiOjN/BeEikyzCet4gJswrE2KUWAmyFCtGH10TQiBnc975K4bMIp5C5kWNAZ0exkhHFTxcaItxvENKeN6dIq0/TLHyLSYooJyiHzTLoXA8JcCtHi0GN0VgIBBhmEGKQUwgx1ifNQG8t6Mg5B5l6P0YKrlOCfIIG835nRuhEnMLtPsj5HybU4BYKBZgzCPl2twMwQg3ncE%2Bd835pB/mDE%2BXpdYpBoU/OeaQOAsAkBKyxHfcglAsjAAUEDEQygGAIEWt8yFpAVo%2BDwICIIPLHCsH5YKmFnzRXiuqMATg6xJAitQP8JVxAUa/llfFElnyWXIE2MQLlbyjWk1SBkfA3zPk0HoEwNgHAeD8EEMIUQKA5ByCEHgVwelIDdFQEsIIelBgly9DMekEggUyE2pMEuAB1NgrAE0o0paCgYggvQOClXygVBq3nCvikcHwRb6WvPecS%2BVZK3mk32o%2BEuj5uCTGAMgZAkxVV9g2dgK12o74blwIQEgFULCcHaoC2QMgoXyrhaQBF3B1h9gsBYakB1HzUmpNwbw6wzDUkfASwYRKvk1vJZSkA1LaWwpeW8yQ1a6W1opTS2d3RZoBA0NwIAA%3D)

Comment: You might even use `static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, recursive_invoke_result_t<F, int>);` instead of printing. for missing `type`, it is also doable, but requires extra helper.