# How to display value and it's data type in c?

Tags: c

int x=10 and after run the code show "10 int"

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int x=10;
        printf("%d %s",x,typedef(x))
    }
```

Comment: You can't. At least 15 characters. You're welcome.

Comment: In c++ can I show?

Comment: "sort of". You won't get `int` in most compilers, though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to print a variable's type in standard C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c)

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't have any run-time type information. The best you can achieve with standard C is to manually list all supported types at compile-time, then at compile-time check which one that was used. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TYPE_STR(x) _Generic((x), \
  int:    "int",                  \
  double: "double",               \
  char:   "char" )                \

int main()
{
  int x=10;
  printf("%d %s",x,TYPE_STR(x));
}
```