# How to deduce if a type is lambda?

Tags: c++, c++20

how to deduce a type is lambda ? like `std::is_function` ?  I've also tried `std::is_invocable`, but it need exactly types of parameters.

Comment: You can check whether it is invokable with specific parameter types. There are arcane techniques for checking whether it has *any* `operator()`, but this is usually not a valid thing to check. In any case, you can't check whether it's specifically a lambda type.

Comment: @BrianBi, I think that is sad but true :(.  I tried many ways...

Comment: It's just an indication that you need to rethink the broader problem you are trying to solve, and find another way that doesn't depend on knowing whether a type is a lambda.

Comment: Lambdas *are not special* in C++. There is never any reason to write a function that can *only* take a lambda. Functions should accept any particular callable object appropriate to its use.

Comment: @BrianBi: Yeah, by my understanding a lambda is syntactic sugar for a standard functor class which a user could write by hand (the captures are constructor arguments, the arguments are the arguments to `operator()`); at best, with RTTI, you might be able to do terrible heuristics to figure out if the underlying name is something the cat spat up (probably a compiler generated name for the lambda) vs. a vaguely human name (though with the name-mangling compilers apply, it's going to look a lot like cat sick too). But even if you can, and even if heuristics work, there's never a reason to do it.

Comment: @VeNToR: I strongly suspect this is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040). *Why* do you think you need to do this? What problem are you solving?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: my code is very long to share it.  I wish I could share ?

Comment: @VeNToR: I'm not asking for all your code. Just an explanation for why you think it's important to *specifically* identify lambdas and handle them differently from other functors, which they are drop-in equivalents for. The explanation could lead to an answer that solves your actual problem; the whole point of XY problems is that you've settled on a bad solution to your real problem, and you're trying to make the bad solution work, neglecting to describe the real problem that has a good solution.

Comment: With https://stackoverflow.com/a/56766138/2193968 you can do https://godbolt.org/z/G9dWrMaW4

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, thanks but this uses runtime processing...

Comment: @VeNToR Well, since string_view doesn't have contains() until C++23 what about this: https://godbolt.org/z/d39Ed69nW

Answer (score 2):

You cannot check for every invocable types without having the exact parameters. Take this for example:

```
auto my_lambda = [](std::integral auto number) {};
```

There are few properties that make it hard to check without knowing the parameter types:

- You cannot take the address of `operator()` since it's a template. You could take the address of `operator()<int>` but you'd have to know the type in advance
- You cannot try the lambda with a "convert to anything" type, since it's not an integral
- There are no other observable properties of the type that can be observed.

That makes it really hard to have a `is_lambda` trait. Also, you could have something like that:

```
struct A {
    void operator()(int) const {}
};
```

This would be indistinguishable from a lambda.

---

There are however, very arcane ways to check if a type is a lambda or not.

I would strongly recommend *not to do that*.

You could theorically check the name of the type by using `__PRETTY_FUNCTION` or `__FUNCSIG__`, and check if the name look like a compiler generated name for a lambda, but that would exclude any other user defined callable types, which are, and should be accepted like lambda.

I leave the implementation as an exercise to the reader.