# Structure Bindings and Move Semantics

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following code snippet:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> myMap;
// ... initializing 'myMap' with some values
for (auto&& [Id, deviceIds] : myMap)
{
    auto l = [deviceIds = std::forward<decltype(deviceIds)>(deviceIds)]() {
        // do something here with deviceIds
        }
}
```

I am trying to move `deviceIds` into the lambda, because the `vector`'s size might be huge.

Will the code above move it or copy for some reason?

Comment: Then why not just use `std::move` like `auto l = [deviceIds = std::move(deviceIds))(){ }`?

Comment: Because `auto&&` is a universal reference which should be moved conditionally and not unconditionally which `std::move` does.

Comment: But in your case, it's not, `deviceIds` are *always* lvalues.

Comment: But every variable is always lvalue. But its type can be either lvalue or rvalue depending whether the passed object was lvalue or rvalue. That's the reason behind using conditional move, awaik,

Comment: Substitute in a move-only type such as `unique_ptr<int>` for `vector<int>` and re-compile.  If the `vector` is being copied, this substitution will not compile.  Else it will.

Comment: @HowardHinnant what if to use `auto&` instead of universal reference and then `std::move`? I am aware that in that case I am intended to change bound objects, but isn't it the case also when using universal reference if the passed object is lvalue?

Comment: @HowardHinnant I changed `vector` to `unique_ptr` and removed code inside `for` loop and it compiles which means that actually structure binding feature initializes `deviceIds` by rvalue. am I right? (otherwise it would not compile) Hence I can really `move` deviceIds unconditionally as @Hewill Kang mentions above.

Comment: Another thing I would like to understand is in what conditions structure binding feature decided copy or move objects into bound object... but this is different story

Comment: I found that exploring your code using one of the `type_name` implementations found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81870/576911) to be quite educational.  For example: `std::cout << type_name<decltype(deviceIds)>() << '\n';`